# Makefile If-Then Else and Loops

Tags: makefile

Can someone explain how to use if-then statements and for loops in Makefiles? I can't seem to find any good documentation with examples.

Comment: I add "with simple examples". The documenatation's ok, but man are the examples abstract! To me, this is still a valid question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Conditional Forms**

Simple

```
conditional-directive
text-if-true
endif
```

Moderately Complex

```
conditional-directive
text-if-true
else
text-if-false
endif
```

More Complex

```
conditional-directive
text-if-one-is-true
else
conditional-directive
text-if-true
else
text-if-false
endif
endif
```

**Conditional Directives**

If Equal Syntax

```
ifeq (arg1, arg2)
ifeq 'arg1' 'arg2'
ifeq "arg1" "arg2"
ifeq "arg1" 'arg2'
ifeq 'arg1' "arg2"
```

If Not Equal Syntax

```
ifneq (arg1, arg2)
ifneq 'arg1' 'arg2'
ifneq "arg1" "arg2"
ifneq "arg1" 'arg2'
ifneq 'arg1' "arg2"
```

If Defined Syntax

```
ifdef variable-name
```

If Not Defined Syntax

```
ifndef variable-name
```

**foreach Function**

foreach Function Syntax

```
$(foreach var, list, text)
```

foreach Semantics
For each whitespace separated word in "list", the variable named by "var" is set to that word and text is executed.

Answer (score 20):

Here's an example if:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(OS)),Linux)
        PYTHON = /usr/bin/python
        FIND = /usr/bin/find
endif
```

Note that this comes with a word of warning that different versions of Make have slightly different syntax, none of which seems to be documented very well.

Comment: Is `$(OS)` a predefined GNU make variable? If so, then maybe you should add it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/714100/912144).

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried the [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals)? It has a whole section about conditionals with examples.

Comment: It is interesting that they waste a lot of words explaining several combinations, but don't mention the most basic thing, that the `ifeq` cannot be indented.

Comment: I wasted couple of hours pulling my hair just to find ifeq cannot be indented... Thankyou for your valuable comment @RafaelEyng

Comment: if `ifeq` cannot be indented, does this imply conditionals cannot be used inside a target?

Comment: Alternate solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602879/413538 that works inside make targets

Comment: "The recipe lines start with a tab character" [ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax), given Conditionals are not Recipe lines, they don't - shrug

Answer (score 5):

You do see for loops alot of the time, but they are usually not needed. Here is an example of how one might perform a for loop without resorting to the shell

```
LIST_OF_THINGS_TO_DO = do_this do_that 
$(LIST_OF_THINGS_TO_DO): 
       run $@ > $@.out

SUBDIRS = snafu fubar
$(SUBDIRS):
     cd $@ && $(MAKE)
```