# Identify Cygwin, Linux, Windows using environment variables

Tags: windows, linux, makefile, environment-variables, detection

The problem arises when makefile needs be run on different OS and various setting should be properly set up (escaping, path separator, etc) depending on OS. 
The first approach was to use Windows COMSPEC:

```
ifneq ($(COMSPEC)$(ComSpec),)
## in windows
else 
## in linux
endif
```

This is false positive for Cygwin, because it sees Windows' environment variables and detects Cygwin as Windows.
Then we tried Linux PWD:

```
ifeq ($(PWD),)
## in windows
else 
## in linux, cygwin
endif
```

However, as a result of integration of off-site tool we have PWD set in windows (one of the perl's modules). So, the detection fails again.

I wonder, what is the best approach to differentiate between Cygwin, Linux, Windows using environment variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile

Comment: Thank you, that may help me someday as well. Actually, this is not duplicate since that question doesn't include Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cygwin and (tested on Ubuntu) Linux provide an `$OSTYPE` environment variable, set to `cygwin` for Cygwin and `linux-gnu` for (Ubuntu) Linux.

Windows does not have this variable, and so it appears to be the only one you'll need. I suppose it's possible that **your** Linux doesn't provide it, in which case you can use `$OSTYPE` to distinguish between Windows and Cygwin and then fall back to `uname` for Cygwin vs. Linux.

Comment: Updated with what appears to be an answer that suits your needs fully.

Comment: This solution seems the most suitable according to the question - accept it.
PS
Seems to be Windows can be distinguished by presence of $OS environment variable.

Comment: *"Windows does not have this variable"* - that's not entirely accurate: git-bash also provides its own shim of `$OSTYPE` (with the value `msys`), so you might wrongfully detect windows as non-windows if you rely on its absence for detection.

Answer (score 1):

Distinguishing between Windows/not Windows using SHELL is not working for me as proposed by pkh. It's appeared that SHELL variable is defined in makefile running by gmake (mine is ver. 3.81) and it equals to "sh.exe". So, the current working solution for me is extend pkh's idea with distinguishing by .exe Windows executable file extension:

```
ifneq ($(findstring .exe,$(SHELL)),)
    $(warning In Windows)
else
    $(warning In Linux/Cygwin)
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have gcc available on all your machines (ie you are compiling something using your makefiles), you could use

```
gcc -dumpmachine
```

to find out the OS for which gcc builds.

You could use the output to set some variables like `WINDOWS`, `LINUX` or store it directly in order to use the information.

Comment: I use another compiler (propitiatory one), checked its help and didn't find any similar option. Actually, the question is about using environment variables and make operations. Anyway, thank you, it may help in case we switch to gcc.

Comment: I've just had a thought, that even we do not use gcc as a compiler, we may use it only for this reason - "identifying OS". Doesn't it seem weird to use a compiler to detect OS. For Windows it shows "mingw32" and for Cygwin "i686-pc-cygwin" on my site. So, I wonder how vary this ouput could be and would it be problematic to distinguish by this output?

Comment: Well, you could (un)set variables like `WINDOWS` or `LINUX` for known outcomes of the `gcc -dumpmachine` command, ie `mingw32` and `i686-pc-cygwin` would set the `WINDOWS` variable and something like `x86_64-linux-gnu` sets the `LINUX` variable. Of course you could look for sub-strings to ease this process. After that you could use these variables in the rest of your makefile(s).

Answer (score 0):

On Cygwin the OSTYPE environment variable needs to be exported for make to see it.