# Suppress make rule error output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have an rule that creates a directory

```
bin:
    -mkdir $@
```

However after the first time the directory has been generated, I receive this output:

```
mkdir bin
mkdir: cannot create directory `bin': File exists
make: [bin] Error 1 (ignored)
```

Is there some way I can only run the rule if the directory doesn't exist, or suppress the output when the directory already exists?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477292/what-do-and-do-as-prefixes-to-recipe-lines-in-make

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The traditional way to handle directory creation is to use a stamp file that is depended on and creates the dir as a side effect. Remove the stamp file when making `distclean` or whatever your "really clean" target is:

```
bin/.dirstamp:
    mkdir -p $(DIRS)
    touch $@

bin/foo: bin/.dirstamp
    $(MKFOO) -o $@

distclean:
    rm -rf bin
```

The reason for this is as follows: whenever a file in `bin` is created/removed, the mtime of the containing directory is updated. If a target depends on `bin`, then the next time `make` runs, it will then recreate files that it doesn't need to.

Comment: Does the dir dep go on all the files generated into that location?

Comment: Every file created in that directory would need to depend, either directly or indirectly, on the stampfile to ensure that it was created before use.

Answer (score 23):

Another way to suppress the `make: error ... (ignored)` output is to append `|| true` to a command that could fail. Example with grep that checks for errors in a LaTeX log file:

```
undefined:
  @grep -i undefined *.log || true
```

Without the `|| true`, make complains when grep fails to find any matches.

This works for all commands, not just mkdir; that's why I added this answer.

Comment: daniel, the `-` prefix character to a command in a make rule does the same thing albeit without requiring the shell to handle it. This is likely faster, and less likely to backfire.

Comment: The `-` prefix causes make to output the annoying "error ignored" output, which my solution doesn't. So no, the two do not do the same thing.

Comment: This only works as ||: (pipe-pipe-colon) on my Windows build.

Answer (score 10):

The error is ignored already by the leading '`-`' on the command line.  If you really want to lose the error messages from `mkdir`, use I/O redirection:

```
bin:
    -mkdir bin 2> /dev/null
```

You will still get the 'ignored' warning from `make`, though, so it might be better to use the option to `mkdir` that doesn't cause it to fail when the target already exists, which is the `-p` option:

```
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

bin:
    ${MKDIR_P} $@
```

The `-p` option actually creates all the directories that are missing on the given paths, so it can generate a a number of directories in one invocation, but a side-effect is that it does not generate an error for already existing directories.   This does assume a POSIX-ish implementation of `mkdir`; older machines may not support it (though it has been standard for a long time now).

Comment: why such `2>&1` redirection help? I would understand `2>/dev/null` to send stderr to oblivion but sending it to stdout.....?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: You're right — a thinko back in 2010.  I've fixed it.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well I ended up with this construct, maybe someone will find it useful or can comment on it:

```
BINDIR = .
TMPDIR = tmp
OUTDIRS = $(BINDIR) $(TMPDIR)
$(OUTDIRS):
    @test -d $@ || mkdir $@
```

Comment: Make does `test` for you anyway, so it ends up stat'ing the directory twice. This just hides the problem that the default target is .(dot).