# How can I reduce makefile boilerplate when doing out-of-source builds and Java?

Tags: java, jar, makefile

I've got a quick and dirty little make file that does out-of-source builds for a relatively small java project:

```
default: bin/classes/EntryPoint.class bin/classes/manifest
    jar cvfm ./bin/output.jar ./bin/classes/manifest -C ./bin/classes EntryPoint.class

bin/classes/EntryPoint.class: ./src/EntryPoint.java bin
    javac -sourcepath ./src -d ./bin/classes ./src/EntryPoint.java

bin/classes/manifest: src/manifest
    cp bin/classes/manifest src/manifest

bin:
    mkdir ./bin; mkdir ./bin/classes;

clean:
    rm -rf bin
```

The downside here is that if I want to add a new java file, I need to add a target for it, and add dependencies to the jar packaging step, and the path to the jar packaging step's command line. Adding the same thing in 3 places is going to result in unmaintainable mess for anything more than 4-5 files.

What I would like to do is simply add a `"SOURCEFILES= files here"` definition and list the files, and not have to mess with the commands and such. Can this be done?

NOTE: I know there are probably better tools for this (such as `ant`), but this is something I'm turning in as a homework assignment, and I cannot require the grader to have anything but the jdk amd `make` installed.

Comment: Is it on linux? You could do includes with linux magic if you are guaranteed to run on linux...

Comment: @bwawok: I believe GNUmake is going to be used, but it could be on a BSD box. Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't wild card character help?

```
javac ./blah/*.java
```

*Updated:* To recurse through sub directories add

```
**/*.java
```

Example:

```
javac -sourcepath src src/**/*.java -d classes -verbose
```

Comment: It helps, but it won't help for subdirectories.

Comment: Try **/*.java that should recurse. Updated the answer above.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. Use four spaces before a line to get `monospaced` text. This also ignores other markup like asterisks. It doesn't trigger unless there's a blank line after the previous paragraph, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can expect GNUMake:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/**/*.java)
CLASSES := $(patsubst src/%.java,bin/classes/%.class,$(SOURCES))

default: $(CLASSES) bin/classes/manifest
    jar cvfm ./bin/output.jar ./bin/classes/manifest -C ./bin/classes EntryPoint.class

bin/classes/%.class: src/%.java bin/.dirstamp
    javac -sourcepath ./src -d ./bin/classes $<

bin/classes/manifest: src/manifest
    cp bin/classes/manifest src/manifest

clean:
    rm -rf bin

bin/.dirstamp
    mkdir -p bin/classes
    touch $@
```

I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477418/suppress-make-rule-error-output/3554442#3554442) why it's better to use a stamp file for directories rather than depending on the directory itself.

Note that if you have classes that depend on each other, you won't be able to compile with this `Makefile`. To compile those, `javac` has to be given both of the source files at once, if I remember correctly.