# Makefiile with many flags

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, linker, intel-mkl

I am trying to learn how a Makefile should look like, when it comes to the flags, especially the linking ones. Here is my Makefile:

```
OBJS    = n.o
SOURCE  = n.cpp
# HEADER = there are no header files, so I commented that
OUT     =       test
CXX     = ../mpich-install/bin/mpic++
FLAGS   =       -I../intel/mkl/include  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a       -Wl,--start-group       ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a    -Wl,--end-group ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a -lpthread       -lm     -ldl

all: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)       $(FLAGS)

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<<
n.o:    n.cpp
        $(CXX)  -c      n.cpp   $(FLAGS)

.PHONY : all
# clean house
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS)
```

and then I am getting:

```
../mpich-install/bin/mpic++     -c      n.cpp   -I../intel/mkl/include  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a       -Wl,--start-group       ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a   ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a    -Wl,--end-group ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a  -lpthread       -lm     -ldl
g++: warning: ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a: linker input file unused because linking not done
../mpich-install/bin/mpic++     n.o -o test     -I../intel/mkl/include  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a       -Wl,--start-group       ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a   ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a  ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a    -Wl,--end-group ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.a  -lpthread       -lm     -ldl
```

That means that I should use some flags only in the last part of the process. What is the correct way to handle such a case? Maybe create `FLAGS1` and `FLAGS2`? It should work, but I want to know which the correct way.

Comment: The flags used for compiling and linking are different. You need to use the appropriate flags for each step in each step. Have a look at the output of `make -qp` (save it to a file) and look at the default rules that make has built-in for compiling and linking C and C++ files. That should help clarify things some.

Comment: You're using `FLAGS` as a generic "i don't care what phase of the build we're in" type of argument -- this isn't the right way to do things. Compilation flags are (mostly) different from linking flags, so you should not be joining them together. Instead, separate your `CFLAGS` (or `CPPFLAGS` in this case) from your `LFLAGS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"... but I want to know which the correct way."*

The correct way is to keep up with `make` standard variable names, in particular `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

You don't want to specify libraries for the linker flags like you try to do here (specifying subjects actually):

```
FLAGS   =  ... ../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_ilp64.a
```

Instead of using `FLAGS` and giving a direct subject for linking, you should rather use the standard `LDFLAGS` makefile variable to setup the path, and let the linker find the appropriate static or shared libraries:

```
  LDFLAGS += -L../intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_scalapack_ilp64
# ^^^^^^^ Note the standard build system uses $(LDFLAGS) at the linker stage rule
# -L specifies the paths for finding libraries
# -l<MyLib> actually searches for certain libraries in the given paths,
#           expanding to search for files like libMyLib.a or libMyLib.so.

all: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o $(OUT) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
#                                          ^^^^^^^^^^ Use them separately at
#                                                     linking stage  
        make    -f      Makefile        clean
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This whole line looks very (!!!) suspicious,
#                                             and would just make it harder to debug your
#                                             build system. It's an indicator, you did
#                                             dependencies management wrong.
#                                             Consider to use the compiler's --MF options 
#                                             family, to create a dependency file for the 
#                                             headers, and include it in your makefile.
```

---

Distinguish from compilation phase flags (`CXXFLAGS`), and linking stage flags (`LDFLAGS`).

---

Aside:

To avoid this

```
make    -f      Makefile        clean
```

action in your final target rule (that was probably added to avoid missing to catch up with header dependencies), add an `-MF` option to the `CXXFLAGS`, and include the results.

Here's more detailed information about the various techniques:

**[Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)**

Comment: So, what `$(FLAGS)` should be in that case?

Comment: @gsamaras `$(CXXFLAGS)`

Comment: No that was not the case. I added that clean so that I can get rid of the objects files that made it hard for the testers to find the source and header files in my project (I had that from a previous Makefile with many files). Now, I am confused and what I have does not compile. Sorry.

Comment: @gsamaras You should better consider an [_out of source tree_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894220/out-of-tree-builds-with-makefiles-and-static-pattern-rules) build to provide the artifacts, and separate them from the source code. Note, that the `clean` target should remove the just created executable target as well.

Comment: I do not think that's the ideal solution here. I think you focus too much into this `make    -f      Makefile        clean`, so I just got rid of it. So just forget it, I am also deleting from the question. Maybe it would be good to edit your answer, since that's not the spirit of my question. I tried to play around with what you have in your answer, but it just fails and I am getting undefined references. I mean I want to accept your answer, but I just can't!

Comment: @gsamaras The main point was, you need to have different flag variables for different stages of constructing artifacts from your makefile. I don't see, how this doesn't finally answers your (a bit unclear) question.

Comment: That's a good comment, I agree. However, what you have there just doesn't compile. Anyway, I got the point, so +1. ;)

Comment: @gsamaras Well, I think you will be interested in having a look at [Using Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) and [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables). Not too much point bothering about.

Comment: @gsamaras Pro tip: Using `make` to create build systems, follow to overide their intrinsic rule and variable namings as much as possible.