# Running Makefile not completely

Tags: c++, makefile

I am a rookie to MaKefile and I've been learning it recently.
However, I got trouble when I tried to run `make` command on my terminal.
Here's my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
bin = ./bin/

makedir:
        @echo "build ./bin"
        mkdir  $(bin)

all: algo

OBJS = $(patsubst %.o, $(bin)%.o, BB.o BF.o method.o algo.o)

algo: BB.o BF.o method.o algo.o
        $(CC) -o algo $(OBJS)

BB.o: BB.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $(bin)$@
BF.o: BF.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $(bin)$@
method.o: method.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c method.cpp -o $(bin)$@
algo.o: algo.cpp method.hpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c algo.cpp -o $(bin)$@

clean:
        -rm -f $(bin)*
        -rmdir $(bin)
        -rm -f algo
```

I tried to put object files in `bin` directory.
But, the terminal only shows:

```
build ./bin
mkdir bin
```

**And here's the problem.** Only a empty directory named `bin` being created.
It seems like it didn't do anything after `mkdir` command.

For more details, it's my directory structure before running `make` command:

```
├── algo.cpp
├── BB.cpp
├── BF.cpp
├── Makefile
├── method.cpp
├── method.hpp
```

I have no idea about it at all, and tried to find any way to solve it but useless.
By the way, I am also a rookie to Stackoverflow.
If I don't ask questions at a good way, let me know and I will get better. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm guessing that `iCC` on the first line is a typo. Using vi?

Comment: yeah.I edited Makefile with vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `make` without arguments, the recipe for the first target in the Makefile is followed.

Your first target is `makedir`, whose recipe performs those two commands and nothing else. So, the computer is doing what you asked it to do.

I recommend that you put the `all` target first, and make `makedir` a prerequisite of the targets that actually do rely on it:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
bin = ./bin/

all: algo

OBJS = $(patsubst %.o, $(bin)%.o, BB.o BF.o method.o algo.o)

algo: BB.o BF.o method.o algo.o
        $(CC) -o algo $(OBJS)

BB.o: makedir BB.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $(bin)$@
BF.o: makedir BF.cpp 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $(bin)$@
method.o: makedir method.cpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c method.cpp -o $(bin)$@
algo.o: makedir algo.cpp method.hpp
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c algo.cpp -o $(bin)$@

makedir:
        @echo "build ./bin"
        mkdir  $(bin)

clean:
        -rm -f $(bin)*
        -rmdir $(bin)
        -rm -f algo
```

There are better ways to handle build output directory creation, though ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3477418/4386278)).

Comment: Also recommended reading for the makedir target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477418/suppress-make-rule-error-output

Comment: @john: Now shamelessly stolen