# What's the Windows command shell equivalent of Bash's `true` command?

Tags: git, bash, shell, cmd

I have written a Vim plugin which shells out to run external commands. Two of the commands I run are `diff` and `grep` which can each exit with a non-zero exit code during "normal" operation.

(`diff` exits with exit code 1 when it finds differences and `grep` exits with exit code 1 when it doesn't find matches.)

For the purposes of my Vimscript I need to return an exit code of 0 from these commands. So far I'm constructing the commands like this:

```
diff a b || true
```

And:

```
grep foo bar || true
```

This works for me on OS X and it apparently works for some Windows users. However, when I run Windows 7 on OS X via VirtualBox, using the Bash installed by the Git installer, I get the error message:

> 'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the correct successful-no-op command to use on Windows?

Comment: As a minor point, `true` and `false` are commands that return 0 (success) and non-zero(failure) to the OS. The need for actual command s are because, as far as I know, the traditional shells didn't have a literal way to specify a boolean.

Comment: They aren't really needed, as by themselves they are identical to `(exit 0)` and `(exit 1)`, respectively.

Comment: @chepner That solved the problem for me; thanks!  I now use `diff a b || exit 0`.  If you can add your comment as an answer I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: When you say "on Windows", do you mean running bash under Windows, or running the Windows `cmd` shell? The answer is likely to be quite different. bash has `false` and `true` as built-in commands, and "`'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`" is a Windows cmd error message, not a bash error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`true` is roughly equivalent to `(exit 0)` (the parentheses create a subshell that exits with status 0, instead of exiting your current shell.

Comment: This did not work on Win 10. When `(exit 0)` is called, either on its own or because of a fall through from a failed command, the shell exits.

Comment: If true, that would appear to be a fairly significant bug in Window's `bash` implementation.

Comment: @chepner: It's not entirely clear, but I believe the OP is looking for an equivalent in the Windows `cmd` shell. If the OP were using bash, no replacement should be necessary; bash has `false` and `true` as built-in commands, and that's not a bash error message. (I don't know what `(exit 0)` does in `cmd`.)

Comment: Did this on Win 10, had the terminal abruptly closed, and felt like the n00b on mIRC when they asked for a way to e.g. change the font color and some smarta** answered ALT+F4. "Tibo has left the chatroom".

Comment: This answer is wrong, paranthesis in `cmd` don't fork anything. `(exit 0)` will cause the script to exit

Comment: as others have explained this is not the correct answer.

Comment: The OP accepted the answer, and seemed pretty clear about using `bash`. If you aren't using `bash` on Wndows, then no, this will not work.

Answer (score 14):

```
VER>NUL
```

works for me.

For example,

```
MKDIR . || VER>NUL
```

issues an error message, but it sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 0.

Comment: `ECHO.>NUL` feels more straightforward for me than `VER>NUL`, because `VER` will have some logic to it that produces the version string which is directed to the `NUL` buffer, whereas `ECHO.` just prints a new line to the buffer, which should be faster.

Answer (score 10):

```
cd .
```

also sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 0 but runs a bit faster and writes a bit shorter than `ver>nul`. Example:

```
mkdir . 2>nul || cd .
```

Comment: This is a smart work around. And how about using `echo SuppressError`

Answer (score 7):

The context is a Windows `cmd` shell (used by the [`git-cmd.bat` script](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat)):

Following "[Exiting batch with `EXIT /B X` where `X>=1` acts as if command completed successfully when using `&&` or `||` operators between batch calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636460/6309)", you could define in your path a `true.bat` file with:

```
@%COMSPEC% /C exit 1 >nul
```

Comment: Win10 64Bit: This solution works for me, the accepted answer doesn't.