# Running "inspect" from boost in a cmake command, getting "svn: E155007: '/home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios' is not a working copy", why?

Tags: svn, makefile, cmake

In the main `CMakeList.txt` of [Zipios](https://github.com/Zipios/Zipios) I have a custom target to run some tools against my code to help cleaning it up once in a while.

Only when I do:

```
make -C ../BUILD zipios_code_analysis
```

I get this error:

> svn: E155007: '/home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios' is not a working copy

Which doesn't seem to make sense to me for two reasons:

1. `inspect` has nothing to do with `svn`
2. I'm using `git` and there are no references to `svn` in the source or binary directories

Here is the custom target:

```
add_custom_target(zipios_code_analysis
    # Make sure we have an output folder
    COMMAND mkdir -p ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis

    # Count the number of TODO, XXX, TBD, FIXME, and \todo
    COMMAND echo "TODO -- output ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis/todo.txt"
    COMMAND sh dev/todo.sh "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis"

    # Search for files with "invalid" (unwanted really) spaces
    COMMAND echo "Spaces -- output ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis/spaces.txt"
    COMMAND sh dev/spaces.sh "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis"

    # Boost inspect tool that reports various problems in the source
    COMMAND echo "inspect -- output ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis/inspect.html"
    COMMAND inspect -tab -crlf -end -path_name -ascii -minmax -assert_macro -deprecated_macro -unnamed -copyright >"${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/analysis/inspect.html"

    # All of these are expected to work on source code so make sure we are
    # in the source code top directory
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

When I run the command manually in my shell, I do not get that error.

Here is the `build.make` with the custom target. I still don't see anything having a link to `svn`?!

```
CMakeFiles/zipios_code_analysis:
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && mkdir -p /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && echo TODO\ --\ output\ /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis/todo.txt
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && sh dev/todo.sh /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && echo Spaces\ --\ output\ /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis/spaces.txt
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && sh dev/spaces.sh /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && echo inspect\ --\ output\ /home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis/inspect.html
    cd /home/snapwebsites/snapcpp/contrib/zipios && inspect -tab -crlf -end -path_name -ascii -minmax -assert_macro -deprecated_macro -unnamed -copyright >"/home/snapwebsites/BUILD/contrib/zipios/analysis/inspect.html"
```

Really, what could possibly add an `svn` command that I would get such an error?

---

### Update

Ah. Actually, if I run the command with a redirect, I get the error:

```
% inspect -tab ... -copyright >a
svn: E155007: '/home/.../zipios' is not a working copy
```

So it does come from inspect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so somehow boost `inspect` wants to check something out in your `svn` code... I suppose boost used (and is still using?) `svn`. That's fine, I liked it too.

Now... why would a tool do that and not give you the option not to do that is strange. Oh well.

I found a hack I can use to fix my problem, though, here is the post with an answer to this problem:

[CMake ignore return on custom target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027063/cmake-ignore-return-on-custom-target)

I changed the command adding `... || true` at the end:

```
COMMAND inspect [...snip...] -copyright >".../inspect.html" || true
```

That way, more or less, make ignores any error inspect is going to emit and my make returns cleanly.