# How to check if running in Cygwin, Mac or Linux?

Tags: bash, shell, cross-platform, cygwin

I have a shell script that is used both on Windows/Cygwin and Mac and Linux. It needs slightly  different variables for each versions.

How can a shell/bash script detect whether it is running in Cygwin, on a Mac or in Linux?

Answer (score 471, accepted):

Usually, `uname` with its various options will tell you what environment you're running in:

```
pax> uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 IBM-L3F3936 1.5.25(0.156/4/2) 2008-06-12 19:34 i686 Cygwin

pax> uname -s
CYGWIN_NT-5.1
```

And, according to the very helpful `schot` (in the comments), `uname -s` gives `Darwin` for OSX and `Linux` for Linux, while my Cygwin gives `CYGWIN_NT-5.1`. But you may have to experiment with all sorts of different versions.

So the `bash` code to do such a check would be along the lines of:

```
unameOut="$(uname -s)"
case "${unameOut}" in
    Linux*)     machine=Linux;;
    Darwin*)    machine=Mac;;
    CYGWIN*)    machine=Cygwin;;
    MINGW*)     machine=MinGw;;
    MSYS_NT*)   machine=Git;;
    *)          machine="UNKNOWN:${unameOut}"
esac
echo ${machine}
```

---

Note that I'm assuming here that you're actually running *within* CygWin (the `bash` shell of it) so paths should already be correctly set up. As one commenter notes, you can run the `bash` program, passing the script, from `cmd` itself and this may result in the paths not being set up as needed.

If you *are* doing that, it's your responsibility to ensure the correct executables (i.e., the CygWin ones) are being called, possibly by modifying the path beforehand or fully specifying the executable locations (e.g., `/c/cygwin/bin/uname`).

Comment: Sometimes less is more ;) BTW, Wikipedia has a table of example uname output at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname

Comment: The Git Bash uname -s output on Windows 7 is `MINGW32_NT-6.1`. Also, there is no `/cygdrive` prefix, just `/c` for `C:`.

Comment: Git Bash isn't Cygwin.  It is MinGW, minimal GNU for MS Windows, which is why the behavior is different.

Comment: I promoted the other answer because this answer doesn't deal with the OP portion `How can a shell/bash script detect ...` and the other does.

Comment: If I run a script under cygwin by executing "\cygwin64\bin\bash -c scriptname", this doesn't necessarily work.  In this situation, the cygwin path doesn't get set up and `uname -s` ends up calling whatever `uname` is first in your current path, which on my system turns out to be the version installed with `geda` which returns the text `WindowsNT`.  It could equally be the MinGW version as described above, though.  A reliable detection for cygwin *must not* rely on the path being set appropriately, IMO.  Therefore, `$(uname -s)` should be changed to `$(/bin/uname -s)` to detect cygwin.

Comment: @Jules, good points but I'm not sure they're relevant. The question talks about running *in* CygWin which I take to mean inside the `bash` shell of it (further supported by the tags). In that case, the paths should already be correctly set. While the path should be able to reach out for Windows executables, they should be *after* all the CygWin stuff. In any case, I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: You can run Bash in Windows 10 without cygwin. uname will return something like: MSYS_NT-10.0-19041 so matching against MSYS_NT*) will do the trick.

Answer (score 395):

## Detect three different OS types (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Windows NT)

### Notes

- In your bash script, use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` to prevent the problem caused by `/bin/sh` linked to different default shell in different platforms, or there will be error like *unexpected operator*, that's what happened on my computer (Ubuntu 64 bits 12.04).
- Mac OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) do not have `expr` program unless you install it, so I just use `uname`.

### Design

1. Use `uname` to get the system information (`-s` parameter).
2. Use `expr` and `substr` to deal with the string.
3. Use `if` `elif` `fi` to do the matching job.
4. You can add more system support if you want, just follow the `uname -s` specification.

### Implementation

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    # Do something under Mac OS X platform        
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" == "Linux" ]; then
    # Do something under GNU/Linux platform
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 10)" == "MINGW32_NT" ]; then
    # Do something under 32 bits Windows NT platform
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 10)" == "MINGW64_NT" ]; then
    # Do something under 64 bits Windows NT platform
fi
```

### Testing

- Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Kernel 3.2.0) tested OK.
- OS X (10.6.8 Snow Leopard) tested OK.
- Windows (Windows 7 64 bit) tested OK.

### What I learned

1. Check for both opening and closing quotes.
2. Check for missing parentheses and braces {}

### References

- [1] [uname - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname)
- [2] [shell script syntax error: unexpected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886268/shell-script-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)
- [3] [Detect the OS from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)
- [4] [BASH Programming Introduction HOW-TO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Comment: For MinGW, it may make more sense to check: `[ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 10)" == "MINGW32_NT" ]`.

Comment: @Albert: expression `"$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)"` is weird a bit.  There are more pretty ways to do that, for example: `if [ \`uname -s\` == CYGWIN* ]; then`. Read it: if `uname -s` starts with *CYGWIN* then...

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I believe it would require double brackets like `if  [[ $(uname -s) == CYGWIN* ]]; then `

Comment: This doesn't detect Cygwin, as was asked in the question.

Comment: Why does this check only the first 5 characters for Linux?  Are there examples of modern Linux distros where `uname -s` will yield something other than "Linux"?

Comment: On 64-bit Windows 10, the third case should read `MINGW64_NT` instead of `MINGW32_NT`.

Comment: @CraigOtis I do not have the environment to test the new modification, if the new codes have bugs, corrections are welcomed.

Comment: ShellCheck will complain about expr usage: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2003

Answer (score 195):

Use **`uname -s`** (`--kernel-name`) because **`uname -o`** (`--operating-system`) is not supported on some Operating Systems such as *Mac OS* and *Solaris*. You may also use just **`uname` without any argument** since the default argument is `-s` (`--kernel-name`).

To distinguish [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) from Linux, [einarmagnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342918/einarmagnus) recommends **`uname -sr`** (`--kernel-name --kernel-release`) as proposed in the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$(uname -sr)" in

   Darwin*)
     echo 'Mac OS X'
     ;;

   Linux*Microsoft*)
     echo 'WSL'  # Windows Subsystem for Linux
     ;;

   Linux*)
     echo 'Linux'
     ;;

   CYGWIN*|MINGW*|MINGW32*|MSYS*)
     echo 'MS Windows'
     ;;

   # Add here more strings to compare
   # See correspondence table at the bottom of this answer

   *)
     echo 'Other OS' 
     ;;
esac
```

The following `Makefile` is inspired from [Git project (`config.mak.uname`)](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/config.mak.uname).

```
ifdef MSVC     # Avoid the MingW/Cygwin sections
    uname_S := Windows
else                          # If uname not available => 'not' 
    uname_S := $(shell sh -c 'uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not')
endif

# Avoid nesting "if .. else if .. else .. endif endif"
# because maintenance of matching if/else/endif is a pain

ifeq ($(uname_S),Windows)
    CC := cl 
endif
ifeq ($(uname_S),OSF1)
    CFLAGS += -D_OSF_SOURCE
endif
ifeq ($(uname_S),Linux)
    CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
endif
ifeq ($(uname_S),GNU/kFreeBSD)
    CFLAGS += -D_BSD_ALLOC
endif
ifeq ($(uname_S),UnixWare)
    CFLAGS += -Wextra
endif
...
```

See also [this complete answer about `uname -s` and `Makefile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777895/938111).

The correspondence table in the bottom of this answer is from [Wikipedia article about `uname`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname#Examples). Please contribute to keep it up-to-date (edit the answer or post a comment). You may also update the Wikipedia article and post a comment to notify me about your contribution ;-)

| **Operating System** | **uname -s** |
| --- | --- |
| Mac OS X | Darwin |
| Cygwin 32-bit (Win-XP) | CYGWIN_NT-5.1 |
| Cygwin 32-bit (Win-7 32-bit) | CYGWIN_NT-6.1 |
| Cygwin 32-bit (Win-7 64-bit) | CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 |
| Cygwin 64-bit (Win-7 64-bit) | CYGWIN_NT-6.1 |
| MinGW (Windows 7 32-bit) | MINGW32_NT-6.1 |
| MinGW (Windows 10 64-bit) | MINGW64_NT-10.0 |
| Interix (Services for UNIX) | Interix |
| MSYS | MSYS_NT-6.1 |
| MSYS2 | MSYS_NT-10.0-17763 |
| [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) | Linux |
| Android | Linux |
| coreutils | Linux |
| CentOS | Linux |
| Fedora | Linux |
| Gentoo | Linux |
| Red Hat Linux | Linux |
| Linux Mint | Linux |
| openSUSE | Linux |
| Ubuntu | Linux |
| Unity Linux | Linux |
| Manjaro Linux | Linux |
| OpenWRT r40420 | Linux |
| Debian (Linux) | Linux |
| Debian (GNU Hurd) | GNU |
| Debian (kFreeBSD) | GNU/kFreeBSD |
| FreeBSD | FreeBSD |
| NetBSD | NetBSD |
| OpenBSD | OpenBSD |
| DragonFlyBSD | DragonFly |
| Haiku | Haiku |
| NonStop | NONSTOP_KERNEL |
| QNX | QNX |
| ReliantUNIX | ReliantUNIX-Y |
| SINIX | SINIX-Y |
| Tru64 | OSF1 |
| Ultrix | ULTRIX |
| IRIX 32 bits | IRIX |
| IRIX 64 bits | IRIX64 |
| MINIX | Minix |
| Solaris | SunOS |
| UWIN (64-bit Windows 7) | UWIN-W7 |
| SYS$UNIX:SH on OpenVMS | IS/WB |
| z/OS USS | OS/390 |
| Cray | sn5176 |
| (SCO) OpenServer | SCO_SV |
| (SCO) System V | SCO_SV |
| (SCO) UnixWare | UnixWare |
| IBM AIX | AIX |
| IBM i with QSH | OS400 |
| HP-UX | HP-UX |

Comment: Thumbs up for Solaris and research above.

Comment: Hi @okutane. I do not understand what you mean. Please provide more details. Do you suggest something? Cheers

Comment: I'm voting up, that's it.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for in order to write a portable/cross-platform `~/.profile` (to set environment variables like `$PATH` -- commenting to provide search keywords for posterity).

Comment: Should probably add Windows Subsystem for Linux now

Comment: Thank you @William for your feedback. I do not have *Windows Subsystem for Linux* but I have found this [`uname` sample](https://linuxhint.com/install_windows_subsystem_linux/). I suppose `uname -s` displays `Linux` on *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, isn't it? Can you confirm?

Comment: This is what ubuntu subsystem for linux displays for me Linux uname -a `DESKTOP-9ETGU1K 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #285-Microsoft Thu Aug 30 17:31:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Thank you @William I have just added "Windows Subsystem for Linux" in the table. Cheers

Comment: I came here because I wanted to detect WSL specifically, and differentiate it from other Linuxes. 

What seems to work for me then is to check `uname -sr` and compare against `Linux*Microsoft)` before `Linux*)`.

Comment: A case solution as shown here  is usually the most elegant & flexible (better than if elif etc). must use it more often

Answer (score 90):

Bash sets the shell variable OSTYPE. From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> Automatically set to a string that describes the operating system on
> which bash is executing.

This has a tiny advantage over `uname` in that it doesn't require launching a new process, so will be quicker to execute.

However, I'm unable to find an authoritative list of expected values. For me on Ubuntu 14.04 it is set to 'linux-gnu'. I've scraped the web for some other values. Hence:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
  linux*)   echo "Linux / WSL" ;;
  darwin*)  echo "Mac OS" ;; 
  win*)     echo "Windows" ;;
  msys*)    echo "MSYS / MinGW / Git Bash" ;;
  cygwin*)  echo "Cygwin" ;;
  bsd*)     echo "BSD" ;;
  solaris*) echo "Solaris" ;;
  *)        echo "unknown: $OSTYPE" ;;
esac
```

The asterisks are important in some instances - for example OSX appends an OS version number after the 'darwin'. The 'win' value is actually 'win32', I'm told - maybe there is a 'win64'?

Perhaps we could work together to populate a table of verified values here:

- Linux Ubuntu (incl. [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)): `linux-gnu`
- Cygwin 64-bit: `cygwin`
- Msys/MINGW (Git Bash for Windows): `msys`
- MacOS Venura: `darwin22.0`

(Please append your value if it differs from existing entries)

Comment: I already like your answer more than mine, fits perfectly on the rare times I've needed this

Comment: Technically, it's not an environment variable, it's a shell variable. That's why you won't see it under `env | grep OSTYPE`, but you will see it under `set | grep OSTYPE`

Comment: For those interested, Bash's `OSTYPE` variable [(conftypes.h)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/conftypes.h) is configured at build time using the exact copy of automake's `OS` variable [(Makefile.in)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/Makefile.in?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#n145). One may consult automake's [lib/config.sub](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/automake.git/tree/lib/config.sub) file for all of the available types.

Comment: also zsh sets OSTYPE

Comment: macOS with HomeBrew Bash show `linux-gnu` .

Answer (score 13):

```
# This script fragment emits Cygwin rulez under bash/cygwin
if [[ $(uname -s) == CYGWIN* ]];then
    echo Cygwin rulez
else 
    echo Unix is king
fi
```

If the 6 first chars of uname -s command is "CYGWIN", a cygwin system is assumed

Comment: `if [ \`uname -s\` == CYGWIN* ]; then` looks better and works the same.

Comment: Yes, but use double brackets: `[[ $(uname -s) == CYGWIN* ]]`. Note also that extended regular expressions are more precise in our case: `[[ $(uname -s) =~ ^CYGWIN* ]]`.

Comment: Above works better, because `expr substr $(uname -s) 1 6` gives an error (`expr: syntax error`) on macOS.

Comment: Note that extended regular expressions are not globs, so to match "any char" after the `CYGWIN` requires `.*`. Adding `*` will only match extra `N`s. So `[[ $(uname -s) =~ ^CYGWIN.*$ ]]` is needed for precision, but for our case `[[ $(uname -s) =~ ^CYGWIN ]]` would suffice

Answer (score 10):

To build upon Albert's answer, I like to use `$COMSPEC` for detecting Windows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]
then
 echo Do something under Mac OS X platform
elif [ "$(expr substr $(uname -s) 1 5)" == "Linux" ]
then
  echo Do something under Linux platform
elif [ -n "$COMSPEC" -a -x "$COMSPEC" ]
then 
  echo $0: this script does not support Windows \:\(
fi
```

This avoids parsing variants of Windows names for `$OS`, and parsing variants of `uname` like MINGW, Cygwin, etc.

*Background: `%COMSPEC%` is a Windows environmental variable specifying the full path to the command processor (aka the Windows shell).  The value of this variable is typically `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`, which typically evaluates to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` .*

Comment: Not correct any more as $COMSPEC is not set when running under the Windows UWS Bash environment.

Answer (score 5):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname

All the info you'll ever need. Google is your friend.

Use `uname -s` to query the system name.

- Mac: `Darwin`
- Cygwin: `CYGWIN_...`
- Linux: various, `LINUX` for most

Comment: I don't have enough rep for a 1-character edit, but that Wikipedia URL should be updated to point to the https version. Can a higher-rep user please do that?

Answer (score 4):

Windows Subsystem for Linux did not exist when this question was asked. It gave these results in my test:

```
uname -s -> Linux
uname -o -> GNU/Linux
uname -r -> 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft
```

This means that you need uname -r to distinguish it from  native Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mingw-w64 gives exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is my way.

```
osis()
{
    local n=0
    if [[ "$1" = "-n" ]]; then n=1;shift; fi

    # echo $OS|grep $1 -i >/dev/null
    uname -s |grep -i "$1" >/dev/null

    return $(( $n ^ $? ))
}
```

e.g.

```
osis Darwin &&
{
    log_debug Detect mac osx
}
osis Linux &&
{
    log_debug Detect linux
}
osis -n Cygwin &&
{
    log_debug Not Cygwin
}
```

I use this in my [dotfiles](https://github.com/wenerme/dotfiles/tree/master/.bashrc.d)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the uname answer is unbeatable, mainly in terms of cleanliness.

Although it takes a ridiculous time to execute, I found that testing for specific files presence also gives me good and quicker results, since I'm not invoking an executable:

So,

`[ -f /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll ] && echo Yep, Cygwin running`

just uses a quick Bash file presence check. As I'm on Windows right now, I can't tell you any specific files for Linuxes and Mac OS X from my head, but I'm pretty sure they do exist. :-)