# How can I run dos2unix on an entire directory?

Tags: linux, dos2unix

I have to convert an entire directory using `dos2unix`. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416768/should-this-question-about-dos2unix-really-be-closed).

Comment: See also: [Unix & Linux: How to apply dos2unix recursively to all the contents of a folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279813/114401)

Answer (score 802, accepted):

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Will recursively find all files inside current directory and call for these files dos2unix command

Comment: i gave like this  find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} /home/venuk/Desktop/NEO_Src  and it gave the error find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: type f = Just 'F'files and not directories for example!

Comment: @vivekgaur, The folder path doesn't go at the end: it goes immediately after the `find`. In this example, it's the dot (i.e., the current directory).

Comment: Note the backslash that escapes the semi-colon ensures the dos2unix commands are separated by semi-colons so that they don't end up mashed together. If you want to run another command afterwards you'll need another semi-colon, so `\;; echo Hello`

Comment: Be careful with this command though, it doesn't check whether the file needs the conversion, so even binary files will be "converted", corrupting them.

Comment: Would this go into subdirectories as well?

Comment: @Pachonk Just tested that and it does.

Comment: @vguzmanp True, the `find` invocation does not do this check (although that would be simple enough to add), but modern `dos2unix` correctly skips binary files.

Comment: @therealjumbo - If you want to use `find` with `-print0` and `xargs`, then you should probably add your own answer. `-print0` is not Posix, so the change could have a negative effect on some users. Considering NickC already provided that variant of the answer, there's little reason to change CyberDem0n's answer.

Comment: My only problem with this command is that it didn't do the dot files in the directory. Using this on a Chef cookbook, there are a few dot files such as `.kitchen.yml`, or `.gitignore` and those were not picked up.

Comment: and to narrow it on a specific extension: `find . -type f -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Comment: you need to pass the `-i` switch to `dos2unix`, or it will just print the converted files to stdout.

Comment: Warning: If you run this command in a directory containing a `.git` index, your git index will be corrupted.

Comment: To avoid `.git` index corruption and preserve UTF-8 BOM, I've ended up doing `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix -ic0 | xargs -0 dos2unix -b`. This command touches only those files (thanks to `-ic0` filtering option), that contain windows line breaks, all other files are skipped. `-b` option is also helpful if your repository contains files with UTF-8 BOM, it preserves the BOM.

Comment: I'd recommend `git ls-files` instead of `find` if you do anything with git repositories.

Comment: Well, so far I have not seen anyone talk about the wildcard "*"
I faced exactly this problem just moments ago and i solved it like this

cd into the target directory and:
 
    `dos2unix *`
All the files in the current directory will be converted to unix format.

Comment: @MichaelAmadi, one limitation is that the wildcard `*` will _not_ access hidden files or folders which begin with a dot (`.`).

Comment: Great answer. I extended it with a multi-process version of this and other answers, plus some new knowledge, showing how to do this on a single dir, on a single dir within a git repo, and on multiple dirs within a git repo, here: [How to recursively run `dos2unix` (or any other command) on your desired directory or path using multiple processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751912/114401).

Answer (score 96):

If it's a large directory you may want to consider running with multiple processors:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 4 dos2unix
```

This will pass 1 file at a time, and use 4 processors.

Comment: This method has the advantage, that it continues, even though dos2unix encounters any problems! Something like a "--force" method. Thank you for that!

Comment: Starting a new dos2unix process for each individual file will introduce massively unnecessary overhead. I'd bump that `n` up by an order of magnitude or two (depending on how many files we're talking about here)

Comment: Great answer! @JonoCoetzee, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751912/114401) I use `-n 50`.

Answer (score 34):

A common use case appears to be to **standardize line endings for all files committed to a Git repository**:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 dos2unix
```

Keep in mind that certain files (e.g. `*.sln`, `*.bat`) are *only* used on Windows operating systems and should **keep** the `CRLF` ending:

```
git ls-files -z '*.sln' '*.bat' | xargs -0 unix2dos
```

If necessary, use `.gitattributes`

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but one thing needs to be addressed: it fails on files with spaces in the path, since `xargs` defaults to having all whitespace be a delimiter. The `xargs` man page shows a `--delimiter` option, but suggests using the `--null` option when input might contain spaces. I have not tested this, but adding `--null` to yours produces the following:
``git ls-files | xargs --null dos2unix``.

Comment: Thanks @Pulseczar - Yes, you are correct, the command will fail if a filename contains spaces. Your comments helped me to find the answer (it also requires `-z` for `ls-files`). I've updated my answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 30):

As I happened to be poorly satisfied by dos2unix, I rolled out my own simple utility. Apart of a few advantages in speed and predictability, the syntax is also a bit simpler :

```
endlines unix *
```

And if you want it to go down into subdirectories (skipping hidden dirs and non-text files) :

```
endlines unix -r .
```

`endlines` is available here https://github.com/mdolidon/endlines

Comment: This is perfect!  The closest one-liner I could get to this is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365679/112190

Comment: How does it improve on `dos2unix`? Genuinely curious.

Comment: 1/ Mainly, there are tons of different `dos2unix`, with varying capabilities (some read UTF32 for example, while some don't ; endlines does not). There's only one `endlines`, which capabilities are well known. 2/ liberal on input, not all `dos2unix` are. 3/ efficient file tree exploration, designed to be fast and practical on tens of thousands of files. 4/ runs out of the box on OSX - which is less important now that Brew package exists.

Answer (score 24):

It's probably best to skip hidden files and folders, such as `.git.` So instead of using `find`, if your `bash` version is recent enough or if you're using `zsh`, just do:

```
dos2unix **
```

Note that for Bash, this will require:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

....but this is a useful enough feature that you should honestly just put it in your `.bashrc` anyway.

If you **don't** want to skip hidden files and folders, but you still don't want to mess with `find` (and I wouldn't blame you), you can provide a second recursive-glob argument to match *only* hidden entries:

```
dos2unix ** **/.*
```

Note that in both cases, the glob will expand to include directories, so you will see the following warning (potentially many times over): `Skipping <dir>, not a regular file.`

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Does the globstar syntax work for dos2unix?  I've used globstar elsewhere with success, but couldn't get this to work.  I'm using Bash 4.3.11(1)

Comment: @NSduToit *NIX style shells don't allow executables to alter the behavior of argument-expansion, because (unlike in Windows) argument-expansion is performed before the executable ever receives the arguments. So the only thing I can think of is that you have some kind of `dos2unix` alias that's affecting how arguments are expanded. What is the output of `type dos2unix` on your system?

Comment: Apologies - seems it works...sort of...  Seems the problem I'm encountering has to do with `dos2unix` and not the actual `globstar`.  It seems if I use `dos2unix` like that it just blindly ignores files that are hidden (start with '.', eg '.vimrc')......?  But the `globstar` itself seems to work - the output of `ls -a **` is as one would expect...

Comment: [Script to test](https://justpaste.it/uwc2) --- you'll see the `dos2unix` command never operates on the `.vimrc` file.  Not the behavior I expected - any insights appreciated :)

Comment: @NSduToit There's some confusion here. My answer explicitly states that the *point* of using `**` instead of `find` is to "skip hidden files and folders, such as `.git`". `dos2unix` never sees the hidden files, because `**` does not expand to show them. If you *want* to automatically run `dos2unix` on hidden files and folders, you can use `find` or `dos2unix ** **/.*` The `**/.*` will expand *only* the hidden files and folders, including `.` (the root dir), `..` (the parent dir), and any other hidden entries in the current folder.

Comment: `type dos2unix` returns `dos2unix is hashed (/usr/bin/dos2unix)`

Comment: (Note that `dos2unix` simply prints `Skipping <dir>, not a regular file.` when run on a directory, so running on `..` and `.` is safe.) Additionally, combining `ls` with a glob is *not* a good way to check how the glob is expanded; use `echo` instead: `echo **` will print the arguments that `dos2unix` receives from `dos2unix **`.

Comment: Thank you!  Makes sense!  Okay, I had a totally wrong idea on what `**` implied, and using `echo` makes it clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113668/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-ns-du-toit).

Comment: @feeela The entire point of the globstar `**` is to make globs themselves exercise recursive descent.

Answer (score 7):

For any Solaris users (am using 5.10, may apply to newer versions too, as well as other unix systems):

dos2unix doesn't default to overwriting the file, it will just print the updated version to stdout, so you will have to specify the source and target, i.e. the same name twice:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 7):

I've googled this like a million times, so my solution is to just put this bash function in your environment.

**`.bashrc` or `.profile` or whatever**

```sh
dos2unixd() {
  find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix
}
```

**Usage**

`$ dos2unixd ./somepath`

This way you still have the original command `dos2unix` and it's easy to remember this one `dos2unixd`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the simplest way is:

```
dos2unix $(find . -type f)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem and thanks to the posts here I have solved it. I knew that I have around a hundred files and I needed to run it for *.js files only.
`find . -type f -name '*.js' -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
for FILE in /var/www/html/files/*
do
 /usr/bin/dos2unix FILE
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although your solution is a valid solution, it would be great if you could add some explanation to it. You might also consider to reference other answers to justify your answer. Please have a look at [answer] for more information.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no sub-directory, you can also take

```
ls | xargs -I {} dos2unix "{}"
```

Comment: If there are no subdirectories, `dos2unix *` is simpler and will actually be more robust than this. (It's generally not recommended to pipe the output of `ls`, because it's a formatting tool and `*` is more reliable for programmatic usage.)

Comment: [the reason piping `ls` is not good](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)