# Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected. module TieConnector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

For ROR development i am using windows subsystem for linux. work on ubuntu 20.

while running rubocop in project shows below issue for each file.

"Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected.

Any solution for same?

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you have a set of files with windows line endings (CRLF) on a unix (LF) system which is causing the warnings.

The rubocop config file allows you to edit the warnings for line endings.

See https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml#L582

To disable, create a `.rubocop.yml` file with the following contents in your application base directory:

```yaml
Layout/EndOfLine:
   Enabled: False
```

To change the line endings to unix style en-masse you can use `dos2unix`.

See [How can I run dos2unix on an entire directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory)

Comment: This worked for me but it should be EndOfLine with a capital O