# RuboCop 'Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected' WSL2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rubocop

I'm currently developing for a Ruby on Rails application. I am on a windows machine, using ubuntu through WSL. We have rubocop setup to track formatting on git pushes, and I always run into the same issue. When adding this comment to the top of any file, I receive the error `Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected`. The issue seems to be talked about here as well [Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected. module TieConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502435/layout-endofline-carriage-return-character-detected-module-tieconnector)

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

The solution here seems to be to disable the warning, or manually convert the files before pushing.

Does anyone know if there is another solution here? I don't believe I can edit the rubocop settings as it is not my project. The converting method does work, but gets a bit tedious to do every time I make a new pull request.

Would there be a way to run the dox2unix convert when running `git push` while targeting the files staged for commit? Or a way to force my machine to use the unix encoding by default?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why don't you just configure your editor or IDE to use `LF` for newlines? Most editors should be able to convert `CRLF` to `LF` automatically when saving a file.

Comment: I believe I'm already doing this. I'm using VSCode, and the end of line sequence is set to LF as opposed to CRLF

Comment: I am not familiar with VSCode but it sounds to me like it is configured to use `LF` for new lines (when you press enter) but like it does not fix existing new lines from `CRLF` to `LF` when they exist for other reasons (legacy code or introduced with copy-paste).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common issue on windows. If you are using vscode you can convert all your files to LF with this shortcut: ctrl + shift + P => 'change all end of line sequence' => Enter => Enter => Enter => 'LF' => Enter Then you can commit and push your code. If it still don't work you might see your git configuration, autocrlf in particular. See this response: stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/7542830

To solve it on a repository level:
`git config --local core.autocrlf input` (on you project root)

Comment: The second method worked for me. Setting `core.autocrlf` to `input` seemed to fix it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure! Also, I don't think it's a rubocop issue. It's rather an issue with the line ending configuration

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RubyInstaller2 (MSYS2 backend, not WSL) and ran into the same issue when RuboCop made some fixes (apparently is used CRLF instead of LF).

I fixed all the files in `vim` with `:bufdo %s/\r//`, but still got the error as the first character was still a CR (or CRLF).

Had to end up using `dos2unix`, as recommended in [Layout/EndOfLine: Carriage return character detected. module TieConnector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502435/layout-endofline-carriage-return-character-detected-module-tieconnector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[EDIT]: Error is intermittent on Windows due to missing BOM: https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop/issues/4669