# Google cloud function deploy throwing /usr/bin/env: 'sh\r': No such file or directory; Error ID: 42fc8383

Tags: java, git, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

A google cloud functions project in java, which has worked perfectly before is suddenly all of a sudden throwing the following error

```
(gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: /usr/bin/env: 'sh\r': No such file or directory; Error ID: 42fc8383
```

This is my deploy command

```
gcloud functions deploy pdf-function --entry-point de.uniba.dsg.cloudfunction.Function --runtime java11 --region europe-west3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --env-vars-file .env.yaml
```

There is no such environment variable named sh\r in the .env.yaml file, nor have I used it anywhere. Also this has ran without any problems previously.

EDIT: This is most likely also a git issue, but I still haven't been able to solve it. I use a windows OS. I have changed between branches in the git and since then the problem started, even though the code is unchanged. I am using gradle as the build tool.

Comment: You might have edited a shell script on Windows; this is coming from a shebang with the wrong line-ending. Try running `npm install` and watch it fail.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Do you have any idea how that might have happened or how it can be fixed? It just worked couple of days ago, and now it just doesn't.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am not facing the same problem for another project.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
Seems to be a line-ending issue as already said.

Use **dos2unix** for the whole source code repo and it worked for me.

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 dos2unix`

Command is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory).