# Trying to build Gem5 on ubuntu 22: native-elf-format: Permission denied or not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, scons, gem5

I am trying Gem5 for the first time and I am using [Learning_Gem5](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part1/building/) as guide.
I have a dual boot system (Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.2) and I am doing this on Ubuntu.

When I reach this step

```
python3 `which scons` build/X86/gem5.opt -j9
```

I encounter an error which terminates the building.

```
scons: Building targets ...
 [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3\r’: No such file or directory
 [     CXX] X86/sim/root.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/sim_object.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/sub_system.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/ticked_object.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/simulate.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/stat_control.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] X86/sim/stat_register.cc -> .o
scons: *** [build/X86/sim/tags.cc] Error 127
 [ TRACING]  -> X86/debug/ClockDomain.hh
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I searched and I found some stuff about making a link to a python directory and changing from CRLF and LF but I couldn't figure out what is going on and what should I do.

Any help is appreciated!

**Update:**
Barmar's right. I used

```
dos2unix cpt_upgrader.py
```

and it was fixed.
But I encountered another problem :(

```
scons: Building targets ...
 [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format > build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format.h
/tmp/tmpiwxnwoqi: 1: build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format: Permission denied
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_to_i64_r_minMag.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_to_ui32.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_to_ui32_r_minMag.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_to_ui64.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_to_ui64_r_minMag.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/i32_to_f128.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/i32_to_f16.c -> .os
scons: *** [build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format.h] Error 126
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

It says that "native-elf-format.h" does not have execute permission. When I give the permission, it says:

```
scons: Building targets ...
 [VER TAGS]  -> X86/sim/tags.cc
build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format > build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format.h
/tmp/tmpu4ahur8f: 1: build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format: not found
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_classify.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_div.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_eq.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_eq_signaling.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_isSignalingNaN.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_le.c -> .os
 [    SHCC] X86/ext/softfloat/f64_le_quiet.c -> .os
scons: *** [build/X86/ext/libelf/native-elf-format.h] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you downloaded files intended for Windows, not Linux. There's a file with CRLF line breaks, which doesn't work on Linux. Since you didn't write this code, I'm not sure what you're supposed to do.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run `python3 `which scons` build/X86/gem5.opt -j9` simply running `scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j9` should work. Unless for some reason you installed a modern scons in a python 2.7 tree..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929461/how-can-i-run-dos2unix-on-an-entire-directory) and ran dos2unix over all of the files in the repository.

Comment: This is a LO answer to another SO question. The question has been closed as a duplicate and this answer should be deleted.