# error in building linphone

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, linphone

i am trying linphone for android . i have followed the steps
1) downloaded the linphone

2) installed ndk, sdk and cygwin and java jdk 
3) set the PATH for sdk>platform-tools and sdk>tools and ndk.

```
./check_tools.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./check_tools.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./check_tools.sh: line 38: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Makefile:67: check_tools.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'check_tools.mk'.  Stop.
```

i get the following errors

i dont know where i am getting wrong

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598753/running-bash-script-in-cygwin-on-windows-7

Comment: when i execute this command C:/cygwin64/dos2unix/bin/dos2unix.exe $make instead of just $make it does not respond for 2 hours am i running it correctly ?