# '\r': command not found - .bashrc

Tags: bash, git, newline

I am trying to build some code in *Linux* and I am getting the error:

```
'\r': command not found
```

Now I know this question has been asked in general before and I *have already* read the answers to them. In this question I am asking for a clarification for my particular situation.

In those questions, the reasons for that error has already been explained: The existence of an invisible character that gets interpreted as a command.

One suggested solution has been to modify the files to eliminate those characters. This solution is not feasible in my case for two reasons:

1. It is impractical to go and modify *all* the files involved
2. It has been expressly ordered to me that I cannot modify the files.

One solution recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481161/4451521) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14607651/4451521) suggest to modify *the EOL behavior in Cygwin by setting an option to ignore CRs:*

The problem is that this `igncr` option has so few documentation that I couldn't find details on this. Is this option available for linux systems too?

(For reference I am working on a git bash in windows to manage the repository but I build the code after transferring it to a linux workstation inside a docker container)

The other possible solution I found was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495560/4451521) in which it was suggested to modify the git settings in order to *configure Git to not convert line endings on checkout:*

How does this config works? In the linked answer it says

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

when I do `git config --list` in my windows machine I get

```
  core.autocrlf=true
```

Should I change the config and clone my entire repository again??

I am looking for clarifications on these two possible solutions but any other solution (that does not involve modifying the files) is fine too

**Just for reference**

I git manage locally a repo on a windows machine. Once finished I transfer the code to a remote linux machine and I build the code there. There is where the problem with \r appears

Comment: What is `core.autocrlf` on your linux workstation? AIUI it needs to be either `input` or `false`.

Comment: right now, it seems not set. I did `git config --list` and all I got was 4 filter.lfs  configurations. I should point out (I know it it weird) that I copy the source file to the WS with scp, so I am not maintaining a repo there

Comment: @KansaiRobot : Is there a particular reason why the files in your repo do have a carriage return to mark the line ending? From my experience, most programs in the Windows world can process text files with either LF or CRLF as terminator.

Answer (score 1):

First, for reasons explained in "[What is the correct core.autocrlf setting I should use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265163/6309)", make sure to add:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Second:

- try and fix your partical file eol (dos2unix [or other commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/6309)), and
- add in a `.gitattributes` file a `myfile eol=lf` directive to force said file to keep the right end-of-line sequence.