# What is the correct core.autocrlf setting I should use?

Tags: git, newline, clone, git-config

Theoretically it is said that when working in a windows machine, people should use `core.autocrlf` set to true.

My windows machine git config settings is `core.autocrlf=true`

However when I clone a gitlab repository I can see that some sh files have their lines finished in `\r`.

(I do that by doing `cat -A thefile.sh`).

This originates all kinds of problems when I copy these files to a linux environment and try to run them.

For reference I cloned the same gitlab repo in a linux machine (where that configuration is not set) and the sh files have no `\r` in them.

My question is, how can I fix this?

Will setting the `core.autocrlf` to input and cloning again the repo will help?
When did these `\r` get introduced?

Answer (score 5):

> What is the correct core.autocrlf setting I should use?

Simple: `false`.

`core.autocrlf` applies to *all* files (including binaries) and can corrupt them on checkout.
Even [`core.safecrlf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresafecrlf) is too encompassing.

I prefer using [`.gitattributes eol` directives](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_checking_out_and_checking_in), where you specify exactly what you need for each file.

Plus:

- `git config` is local, and not versioned: you would rely on other developers to make the exact same "correct" configuration;
- `.gitattributes` is versioned: other developers will benefit from it automatically;
- `core.autocrlf` would override any `.gitattributes` carefully set directives.

So in your case, in a `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.sh         eol=lf
```

See more examples in "[Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34810209/6309)".

Note:

> have their lines finished in \r

I suspect rather: `\r\n` not  `\r` (see [Newline representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation))