# How to remove files from repository listed in .gitignore without changing whitespace

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have read about how to remove files that are in the ignore file from a repository using git commands here: [Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore).

I am using Visual studio 2019 with a repository in Azure DevOps. I have used these steps:

1. From the Git Explorer Menu, "Open in Command Prompt"
2. `git rm -r --cached .`
   This tells git to stop tracking everything and now I have all my files showing as deleted in "Staged Changes" and a smaller number of files showing as added in "Changes". This looks good. I assume ignored files are not added back again, so when I commit those additions all the files that should have been ignored in the first place will be deleted on the server.
3. Stage. Now it looks like there's a problem. The added files are showing as modified.
4. Push to see what they look like when I view the changes in the browser:
   "Only showing the first 999 changes. Click here to load more". And every file I can see has a warning: "The file differs only in whitespace"

I'm guessing it's about line endings but it makes it nearly impossible to review the changes. Is there a way to stop the whitespace changes occurring when I use this process? Or to reverse the whitespace changes? Or tell git to only check in the deletes?

**TLDR Answer** ([from VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68673681/150342)):

```
git rm -r --cached .
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git add --renormalize .
git add .
git commit
```

Comment: *To stage a file* means *to make sure that the file will exist (in some particular form) in the next commit*. If your goal is to *remove* the file from the next commit, why are you staging it again at all? (It's possible that this is some sort of idiocy imposed by VS2019; GUIs are notorious for imposing bad decisions on users.)

Comment: @torek this is the outcome of the git command `git rm -r --cached .` - nothing to do with VS2019 as far as I can tell. Removing all files from the index then adding them back with `git add .` (so that the .gitignore configuration is honoured) appears to be a common way of fixing a repository. My problem is that this is introducing whitespace changes

Comment: @torek To clarify, I cannot commit the result of `git rm -r --cached .` because this will delete all my files so I have to stage the files I want to keep again and they are being added to the commit even though they should be unchanged. Yossarian...let out a respectful whistle. 'That's some catch, that catch-22,' he observed.

Comment: Removing files doesn't *fix* a repository. It does not *break* a repository. It just means that the next *commit you make* will *lack the files*. That's it—that's all there is in a repository: a series of commits. Each commit has the files it has, and that's it. A repository is simply a collection of commits, with each commit containing some files, plus some metadata.

Comment: You seem to be working with what's usually called an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): you want to get something done, and have the impression that `git rm --cached` followed by `git add` followed by `git commit` is the thing that will get the something done. But you haven't said what the *something* is, and clearly this solution-Y doesn't actually work...

Comment: @Torek so the _something_ is that I want to _remove files from the repository that are specified in `.gitignore` without changing whitespace_ (in the files that remain). I'd prefer not to go through it folder by folder manually

Comment: @torek my _problem_ is that the repository contains files that should not have been committed. So yes, I don't need to fix the _repository_ I need to fix the problem _in_ my repository. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Well, if you toss out Visual Studio entirely, and ignore the fact that you can't modify existing commits—only new ones—a simple `git rm --cached` of each file you want to not include in the next commit, followed by a simple `git commit`, will do the trick. Don't `git add` *anything*, just remove the specific files you want removed. (Incidentally, I realize you must be feeling some frustration here—I would be if I were forced to use Windows—but somehow I feel like the [engineer in the old joke](https://otfjokes.com/profession-jokes/manager-jokes-with-engineer/)).

Comment: As I said, I'd prefer not to go through it manually folder by folder, file by file. What I want to remove is defined in the `.gitignore` file. Feeling frustrated mainly by the way git handles line endings, I think

Comment: do the changes go away if you view `git diff -w` vs `git diff`?

Comment: If you're using Windows, you may find you have CRLF issues, which are a̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶n̶y̶ ̶p̶r̶a̶n̶k̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶a̶j̶o̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶n̶y̶ solvable by disabling it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf

Comment: @ti7: That's almost certainly the case, but I didn't want to get into that whole rathole here—the OP is already having to fight both Git and VS. Having a simple list of files to remove, and using `git rm --cached $(cat list)` or similar, would be the way to go on a sane system. Of course this whole problem might never have come up on the sane system in the first place...

Comment: The engineer in the balloon is quite a good joke. Reminds me of the saying about consultants being like sea gulls. _They fly in make a lot of noise, do nothing, and when they leave your left with a big mess_   :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Stage. Now it looks like there's a problem. The added files are showing as modified.

Repeat the same process, but before step 3 (staging), add:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

That will make sure there is automatic eol (end of line) transformation.
See if a `git add .` (or `git add --renormalize .` [with Git 2.16+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309)) followed by a `git status` still show everything as modified.

The [OP Colin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150342/colin) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641723/how-to-remove-files-from-repository-listed-in-gitignore-without-changing-whites/68673681#comment121371959_68673681) the following working:

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git add --renormalize .
git add .
```

Comment: `git add .`  after `git config --global core.autocrlf false` was a significant improvement - it still modified js, html, php, asp, txt, pubxml, svg, css, scss files wherease previously _everything_ was modified

Comment: but `git add --renormalize .` followed by `git add .` did the job. Many thanks.

Comment: Another thought - I've changed a global configuration setting here. Are there any ongoing implications to this? Should I change it back now the exercise is complete?

Comment: @Colin If you want, but this is one global configuration I would recommend anyway, so keeping it is not a bad idea. Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265163/6309 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this way more complicated than necessary. To remove files from git, you just do the following:

```
git rm <files>
git add .
git commit
```

Replace `<files>` with the names of the files you want to remove. You can use standard glob syntax to match more than one file.

This will remove files that have previously been committed. There is no reason to use `--cached` or anything with `autocrlf`. These just complicate the issue.

Comment: I want to remove files as specified by the .gitignore. I'm afraid this answer misses the point of the exercise.

Comment: @Colin Will you elaborate on what this answer misses?

Comment: I don't think your answer tells me how to remove files from the repository specified by the .gitignore does it? In my question I describe one way of doing it - remove _everything_ from the index then stage everything except what is specified in the .gitignore. If I commit after removing _everything_ I delete _everything_ from the repository. But I need to "keep" some of those files I just removed - the ones that are _not_ in the .gitignore. And by "keep" I mean don't delete them from the repository by removing and committing

Comment: @Colin ok, I understand what you mean now. I originally thought that you meant that there are some files that you want to keep in the file system but don't want to track in git.

Comment: @Colin I have updated my answer. I am completely confused what whitespace has to do with your question. Removing files from git shouldn;t be as complicated as you are trying to make it. I don't see any reason to use `--cached` or any other flags.

Comment: @Colin Or maybe I completely misunderstand your question. Are these files committed already and you want to remove them? Or are they only staged and you are trying to remove them from the index? The title says "remove files from the repository" which implies they have already been committed. But you seem to be interested in staged files, but I'm not clear about why.

Comment: Yes the files are committed already. I want to remove the files specified in the .gitignore from the repository and I want to do it without going through the task folder by folder, file by file. So `git rm <files>` doesn't cut it because I need to specify `<files>` manually.
I am interested in staged files because the outcome of the `rm` operation is that the files are staged in a deleted status.
And the reason I'm interested in whitespace is because git changes the line endings if I remove a file from the index and add it again

Comment: I honestly don't know if the `--cached` (remove only from index not working tree) flag is necessary. But the `-r` flag is required to recurse folders