# Ubuntu subsystem on Windows - changes line endings even though I've defined the core.autocrlf to true

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm launch VSCode from an Ubuntu commandline on my Windows machine.
I noticed that it was changing the line endings from the default Windows line ending.  Specifically, when I was doing git diffs, I would see stuff like this:

[image]

Notice the ^M

So I read an article about how to fix this and it suggested the following git config change:

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

But I'm still seeing these line endings being used when I update my code.

Comment: I think you need to tell your vscode to use a consistent EOL : see https://dev.to/wagslane/how-to-get-consistent-line-breaks-in-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf-2c3p

Comment: You should never (well, hardly ever) use `core.autocrlf`. Use `.gitattributes` files instead. (That's only part of the problem, the other part is VSCode itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you would read from me is: "[What is the correct core.autocrlf setting I should use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265163/6309)"

Meaning:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then, as mentioned in "[Disable git EOL Conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21822812/6309)":

```
git add --renormalize .
```

Using [`.gitattributes` `core.eol` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209806/6309) is the right approach to fix eol.
And you can check what is applied to which file with:

```
git ls-files --eol
```