# `git add --renormalize .` doesn't do a thing, how to fix it?

Tags: git, line-breaks, gitattributes, end-of-line

I have the following definition of `.gitattributes`:

```
*.sh text eol=lf

* text eol=crlf
```

if git works properly, it should reformat all `*.sh` file under the current directory into using `lf` as the only end-of-line.

Unfortunately, after running `git add --renormalize .`, nothing happens.

How could this happen? Is git implementation buggy for this feature? If not, what is the correct command to enforce `.gitattributes`?

Comment: Are you expecting it to impact the files _on disk_ or _as they're recorded in the staging area_?

Comment: when I paste your `gitattributes` content in a test repo, I repeatedly get : `* is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:3` (`*` refering to the second `*` on third line). I think you will have to be a bit more explicit on what a text file is.

Comment: What `git version` do you have ? mine is 2.42.0, it may be more verbose about some errors than older versions.

Comment: my version is 2.34.1, let me try to upgrade ...

Comment: @LeGEC ah, sorry I made a mistake (the file name was also wrong), they are correct but the effect is identical

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if I remember correctly, this command should affect all files, not only staged or modified file

Answer (score 1):

When using your `.gitattributes` file in a test repo, I get repeated warnings each time I add a new file:

```
* is not a valid attribute name: .gitattributes:3
```

`*` refers to the second `*` on your last line, when I change that line to `* text eol=crlf`, `git` correctly preserves `lf` in `.sh` files and turns my `lf` into `crlf` in other files (I run on linux, with `git version 2.42.0`)

---

I think your `.gitattributes` doesn't apply because it has an invalid content.

Perhaps the error message isn't shown in your case -- for example, GUI clients sometimes hide the warning messages --, or perhaps older versions of git didn't warn explicitly about as many things.

I don't think saying "everything is a text file" is a good fix: it would mess with your binary files and tru to turn `\10` (=`lf`) into `\13\10` (=`crlf`).

You should either choose a more explicit list of things to consider as a text file, or drop that last line entirely and rely on git's default behavior.

If you have an ulterior motive to absolutely commit files with `crlf` in them, please explain in more details your requirements.

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately it doesn't work under Windows, "sh" file still got CRLF everywhere

Comment: @tribbloid: do you have `autocrlf` enabled ? according to [a reliable source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265163/86072), the `autocrlf` config setting takes precedence over `.gitattributes`

Comment: ah that may make sense, let me verify that

Comment: right now the setting is "core.autocrlf=input" either this or null should be the default value

Comment: yep, it is the default value: $ git config --unset core.autocrlf
$ git config -l
...
core.autocrlf=input
...

Comment: just found another strange problem: the autocrlf on Windows is always set to false even if I changed the value in ./.git/config, I wonder where that value came from

Comment: `git config --show-origin core.autocrlf` will show you what file the setting comes from