# '\r': command not found

Tags: shell

```
echo "Select your option:"
echo "1. Change ip address"
echo "2. Add route"
echo "3. Reboot"
echo "4. Exit"
read A
case $A in
    1)
            echo "Add Ip address"
            read IP
            echo "Add Netmask"
            read Netid
            echo "Add name of interface"
            read Interface
            ifconfig ${Interface} ${IP}/${Netid}
            if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
                    echo "Ip address not configured"
            fi
            ;;
    2)
            echo "Add Destination"
            read dst
            echo "Add Netmask"
            read Netid
            echo "Add Gateway"
            read gw
            route add $dst mask $Netid gw $gw
            if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
                    echo "Route not added"
            fi
            ;;
    3)
            reboot
            ;;
    4)
            echo "Bye"
            exit 0
            ;;
    default)
            echo "Wrong selection"
            exit 1
esac
```

Error:

```
[b104@b104 Downloads]$ ./NetworkUtility.sh 
./NetworkUtility.sh: line 1: $'\r': command not found
Select your option:
1. Change ip address
2. Add route
3. Reboot
4. Exit
1
': not a valid identifier 7: read: `A
./NetworkUtility.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found
./NetworkUtility.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'/NetworkUtility.sh: line 9: `case $A in 
[b104@b104 Downloads]$
```

Comment: Your script file contains DOS/Windows style line endings (`\r\n`), this is what confuses your shell. Try to save it with unix line endings (`\n`).

Comment: You can execute `tr -d "\r" < NetworkUtility.sh > cleaned.sh`, then check if `./cleaned.sh` works better.

Comment: The most unfortunate thing about this question is how long it is -- there's absolutely no reason to have a more-than-20-line script when a two-line one (with a shebang and a single empty line) would produce the exact same problem.

Comment: If you developing using IntelliJ on Windows but executing scripts on Linux, you might have such issue due to default intelliJ line endings configuration. You can solve it by configuring Unix endings as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-endings-and-line-separators.html

Comment: If you develop in VSCODE there is a button to select the line terminator (LF, CRLF) in the status bar. Selecting LF (UNIX environments) and recreating the line breaks in the code would help solve the problem. This helped me :)

Answer (score 48):

It seems that you have Windows style line endings (`\r\n`) - you need to change them to unix style (`\n`). If you have `dos2unix` installed you could use it. You could also do it using `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: and the sed command would be... `sed 's/\r\n/\n/g'`, or ?

Comment: sed command would be `sed 's/\r$//'`, but why not just `dos2unix`?

Comment: Beacause not all distributions have `dos2unix` installed by default.

Comment: You just saved my dev team so, so much time. Strange issues, all resolved because the *one* guy running windows on the team was checking out files as `CRLF`. A million internet points to you.

Answer (score 34):

Its End of Line(EOL) conversion issue when script is written in windows using some editors like **notepad**, **notepad++**(tested).

Sed , tr may solve the issue in case of you just need to run script, however  if you are developing shell script its become annoying each time first convert using, sed/tr command then run your script.

Notepad++ has an option to convert END OF LINE CONVERSION(EOL).
How to do that:
go to **Edit > EOL Conversion >** select **Unix/OSX**

Here you go, save script file and run it.

[Here is screenshot of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guH4E.jpg)

Comment: your suggestion using notepad++ worked for me,

Comment: Worked for me in notepad++  .Edit-->EOL conversion-->unix and save.
Rerun shell script and it worked.

Answer (score 25):

The error happens, because shell doesn't understand DOS/Windows-like line endings and it expects LF instead of CRLF.

You'll need to first configure your editor to use Unix-like line endings or use `dos2unix` command to change it automatically, e.g.

```
dos2unix ./NetworkUtility.sh
```

Read more details at: [`'\r'`: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11616835/55075).

If you're using Vagrant, check: [Windows CRLF to Unix LF Issues in Vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28651275/55075)