# Kernel bash scripts compilation error

Tags: android, git, bash, linux-kernel, line-endings

Last time I tried to compile kernel for my device that runs android, I faced strange issues, shown here with the following errors:

```
/cmsource/kernel/samsung/msm7x30-common/scripts/mkmakefile: line 5: $'\r': command not found
cmsource/kernel/samsung/msm7x30-common/scripts/mkmakefile: line 12: $'\r': command not found
/cmsource/kernel/samsung/msm7x30-common/scripts/mkmakefile: line 59: warning: here-document at line 24 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
cmsource/kernel/samsung/msm7x30-common/scripts/mkmakefile: line 60: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The `mkmakefile` is [bash script](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/mkmakefile) as you know

I tried to solve the compilation errors but I couldn't figure it out.

I suspecting from this: I made a various changes in git in one week ago like the following changes:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
git config --global core.whitespace trailing-space,space-before-tab,inden
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

I saw the following post while I was searching on net: [the post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873293/5828698)

I must say that I downloaded kernel source with using `git clone`

So it seems to me there is a relationship between setting git crlf, line ending settings and kernel compilation errors caused by scripts

Can anyone shed the lights on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with `git config --global core.autocrlf true` is that it is a global setting which can affect *all* your files, including ones whose eol (end-of-line) characters should not be changed
([I found it problematic in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309)).

Try first:

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

And clone again your repo to see if the issue persists.