# Executin hadoop namenode -format

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to do work on hadoop so for that i use:-

Java 1.6
Eclipse Europa 3.3.2
Installing Cygwin
hadoop 0.19.1
 when i use the command error occur:-

```
$ hadoop-*/bin/hadoop namenode -format
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 10: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 13: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 16: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 19: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 29: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 32: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 35: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 38: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 41: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 46: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 49: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 52: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/hadoop-0.19.1/bin/../conf/hadoop-env.sh: line 55: $'\r': command not found
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\CYGWIN~1\home\user\HADOOP~1.1\/build/native
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/CYGWIN~1/home/user/HADOOP~1.1/build/native
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
/bin/java: No such file or directoryC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37
/bin/java: No such file or directoryC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37
/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37
```

can anyone help me to remove this error.
thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a problem with your newline characters which prevents hadoop to find your java binaries. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/cygwin-r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile) question on stackoverflow.

Try running `dos2unix` on your `hadoop-env.sh`.