# Configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu-toolchain

I am trying to build GNU toolchain for OpenRISC by following the guide given at http://openrisc.net/toolchain-build.html on Fedora Virtual Box Image.

I am getting error saying

```
Configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ../gcc-svn/config.sub
```

when I try to configure gcc.

I am new to Linux. I could not find any solution online. Any help to solve the issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Open config.sub with a hex editor to see if the line endings are \r\n instead of just \n. If so, make a backup of the entire folder and then type:

dos2unix *

That will change all line endings from \r\n to \n, and it does it in place, overwriting each file. Then, again try:

./configure   (with any options you desire)

I had this problem on cygwin for Windows where GitHub had converted all files to \r\n, so I had to convert them back with dos2unix.

Comment: Or without installing dos2unix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32912867/360211 `sed -i 's/\r$//' filename`

Comment: Helped me with solving my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

1.check and install libtools

```
yum install libtool       
yum install libtool-ltdl    
yum install libtool-ltdl-devel
```

2.try run "../gcc-svn/config.sub" through shell

```
/bin/bash ../gcc-svn/config.sub
```

see if shows as follows:

> [root@centos jemalloc]# /bin/bash ./config.sub
>   : command not foundine 6:
>   : command not foundine 8:
>   : command not foundine 30:
>   : command not foundine 31:
>   : command not foundine 39:
>   : command not foundine 42:
>   : command not foundine 50:
>   : command not foundine 57:
>   : command not foundine 59:
>   : command not foundine 72:
>   : command not foundine 82:
>   : command not foundine 85:
>   '/config.sub.bak: line 88:    syntax error near unexpected token in
>   '/config.sub.bak: line 88: `  case $1 in

3.find the system config.sub

```
 find / -name config.sub
```

it shows:

```
/usr/share/libtool/config/config.sub
```

compare the two config.sub to see if they are similar.

4.replace `config.sub` with system file

```
mv ../gcc-svn/config.sub ../gcc-svn/config.sub.bak
cp /usr/share/libtool/config/config.sub ../gcc-svn/config.sub 

mv ../gcc-svn/config.guess ../gcc-svn/config.guess.bak
cp /usr/share/libtool/config/config.guess ../gcc-svn/config.guess
```

5. make to see if it works out.

Comment: I was trying to `./configure` a library and the _config.guess_ and _config.sub_ files where way outdated. Replaced both with the ones that came with libtools and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is the first line  of your ../gcc-svn/config.sub file?  I'm guessing it may have a typo.  It should be

```
#!/bin/sh
```

and not

```
/bin/sh
```

If it is

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Make sure that the file /bin/sh exists and is executable

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

Should show something like

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb  3  2009 /bin/sh
```

Comment: Dear me, I certainly hope it isn't world-writable! :)

Comment: :D oversight.  on my machine it was actually "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb  3  2009 /bin/sh -> bash" but I thought that was confuse since it I didn't think it was usually a link.  so I quickly deleted the "l" without thinking about the rest.  Good point ;)

Comment: The first line is #!/bin/sh and ls -l /bin/sh is giving the expected output. But the problem still exists.

Comment: Is the config.sub file executable?