# What is wrong with my string substitution using sed on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, sed

I want to replace `#Banner none` with `Banner /etc/sshd_banner` that is within `/etc/sshd_config`. If I run

```
sudo sed -i "s/#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/sshd_banner" /etc/sshd_config
```

I get the following error

> sed: 1: "/etc/sshd_config": unterminated substitute pattern

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Add a terminating / to the substitute expression.  Ala `"s/#Banner none/Banner \/etc\/sshd_banner/"`

Comment: That did not seem to work.

Comment: ?  Meaning...?  The substitute didn't work, or the error message didn't go away?   One of the neat things about sed is that / is just a convention for the delimiter.   Try  `sed "s|#Banner none|Banner /etc/sshd_banner|" infile` to simplify the readability.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

> Use another delimiter

Eks here I do use `"` as delimiter

```
sudo sed -i "" "s|#Banner none|Banner /etc/sshd_banner|" /etc/sshd_config
```

By changing the delimiter, you do not need to escape the `/`

Your original post missed one `/` at the end.

From OS X manual

```
-i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension
         is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when
         in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk
         space is exhausted, etc.
```

`zero-length` = `""`

Comment: As Jubobs pointed out, it'll need to be `sed -i .bak ...` the -i needing an extension to use for a backup file.

Answer (score 89):

Three problems with your command:

1. You're missing the terminating `/`.
2. You can't use `/` as delimiter anyway, because this character occurs in the string you're trying to replace/substitute. You should use a different character, such as a pipe character, as delimiter.
3. In the version (BSD) of `sed` that ships with Mac OS X, the `-i` flag expects a *mandatory* `<extension>` argument, which your command is missing. An empty string (`""`) should follow the `-i` flag if you want to edit the file in-place with this version of `sed`.

In summary, try

```
sudo sed -i "" "s|#Banner none|Banner /etc/sshd_banner|" /etc/sshd_config
```

Comment: part 3 of this answer was super helpful, i could not find this information elsewhere while googling - OS X's version of sed is May 2005 BSD version, syntax is different in this case from GNU sed

Comment: @phoenixdown in general prefer `man` over Googling because point 3 is explicitly mentioned in the manual for sed which you can find by doing `man sed` or more pedantically `man 1 sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try single quotes. Also, some Seds require that you escape the first delimiter if you want to use something other than `/`.

```
sudo sed -i 's\:#Banner none:Banner :etc/sshd_banner:' /etc/sshd_config
```

One more thing is that `#` is possibly being interpreted as a comment that goes on up to the end of the line.