# How to add lines after a pattern using sed

Tags: macos, shell, sed

In shell script, how can I add lines after a certain pattern? Say I have the following file and I want to add two lines after `block 1` and `blk 2`.

```
abc
def

[block 1]
    apples = 3
    grapes = 4

[blk 2]
    banana = 2
    apples = 3
```

`[block 1]` and `[blk 2]` will be present in the file.

The output I am expecting is below.

```
abc
def

[block 1]
    oranges = 5
    pears = 2
    apples = 3
    grapes = 4

[blk 2]
    oranges = 5
    pears = 2
    banana = 2
    apples = 3
```

I thought of doing this with `sed`. I tried the below command but it does not work on my Mac. I checked [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592043/what-is-wrong-with-my-string-substitution-using-sed-on-mac-os-x) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694980/using-sed-insert-a-line-below-or-above-the-pattern) but I couldn't find what I am doing wrong.

```
$sed -i '/\[block 1\]/a\n\toranges = 3\n\tpears = 2' sample2.txt
sed: 1: "sample2.txt": unterminated substitute pattern
```

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help!

[Edit]
I tried the below and these didn't work on my Mac.

```
$sed -E '/\[block 1\]|\[blk 2\]/r\\n\\toranges = 3\\n\\tpears = 2' sample2.txt
abc
def

    [block 1]
        apples = 3
        grapes = 4

    [blk 2]
        banana = 2
        apples = 3

$sed -E '/\[block 1\]|\[blk 2\]/r\n\toranges = 3\n\tpears = 2' sample2.txt
abc
def

    [block 1]
        apples = 3
        grapes = 4

    [blk 2]
        banana = 2
        apples = 3
```

Awk attempt:

```
$awk -v RS= '/\[block 1\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 3" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS}
      /\[blk 2\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 5" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS} 1' sample2.txt
abc
def

    [block 1]
        apples = 3
        grapes = 4

    [blk 2]
        banana = 2
        apples = 3
    oranges = 3
    pears = 2

    oranges = 5
    pears = 2
```

Comment: try without inplace or give a backup name.

Comment: I still get an error. 
sed '/\[block 1\]/a\n\toranges = 3\n\tpears = 2' sample2.txt
sed: 1: "/\[block 1\]/a\n\torang ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the text provided to the [`a` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Appending-text-after-a-line) has to be on a separate line:

```
sed '/\[block 1\]/ {a\
\toranges = 3\n\tpears = 2
}' file
```

and all embedded newlines have to be escaped. Another way to write it (probably more readable):

```
sed '/\[block 1\]/ {a\
    oranges = 3\
    pears = 2
}' file
```

---

Also, consider the [`r` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Read-text-from-a-file) as an alternative to the `a` command when larger amounts of text have to be inserted (e.g. more than one line). It will read data from a text file provided:

```
sed '/\[block 1\]/r /path/to/text' file
```

---

To handle multiple sections with one `sed` program, you can use the alternation operator (available in ERE, notice the `-E` flag):

```
sed -E '/\[block 1\]|\[blk 2\]/r /path/to/text' file
```

Comment: Or you can use `sed '/\[bl\(k\|ock\) [12]\]/ {a\ ...` (and 4-spaces instead of a `\t`)

Comment: I tried both these and the file didn't get updated.
1. sed -E '/\[block 1\]|\[blk 2\]/r\\n\\toranges = 3\\n\\tpears = 2' sample2.txt
2. sed -E '/\[block 1\]|\[blk 2\]/r\n\toranges = 3\n\tpears = 2' sample2.txt

Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Actually, (escaped) alternation operator (`\|`) in BRE is a [GNU `sed` extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-to-basic-regular-expressions-4). In [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html), only ERE allows alternation.

Comment: @SyncMaster, if you want an inplace update, add the `-i` flag.

Comment: @SyncMaster, if you want to use `r` command, store the text to be added into a separate file, then reference it with `r file` (see my answer, `/path/to/text` is path to your text file, the contents of which will be inserted).

Comment: @SyncMaster, or just try the first (or second) example. You can simply copy & paste it, without creating an intermediate file you need for the last two examples.

Comment: ANSI-C quoting can be used to insert newlines: $'\n'

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work with empty `RS`. This breaks each block into a single record.

```
awk -v RS= '/\[block 1\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 3" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS} 
      /\[blk 2\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 5" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS} 1' file

abc
def
[block 1]
    apples = 3
    grapes = 4
    oranges = 3
    pears = 2

[blk 2]
    banana = 2
    apples = 3
    oranges = 5
    pears = 2
```

Comment: I didn't get the expected output. The new lines did not get inserted in [block 1]. 
This is what I got when I ran this. 
$awk -v RS= '/\[block 1\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 3" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS}
>       /\[blk 2\]/{$0 = $0 ORS "\toranges = 5" ORS "\tpears = 2" ORS} 1' sample2.txt
abc
def

    [block 1]
        apples = 3
        grapes = 4

    [blk 2]
        banana = 2
        apples = 3
 oranges = 3
 pears = 2

 oranges = 5
 pears = 2

Comment: Strange... OSX should use `'\n'` as it's end of line -- the same as Linux (unlike pre-OSX that used `'\r'` instead)

Comment: Same issue on my Linux machine too

Comment: @SyncMaster: This has been tested on OSX awk. [Here is a working demo](https://ideone.com/E6lqAH)

Comment: Also make sure your input file does not have DOS line ending (carriage returns). Check with `cat -A  sample2.txt` command. If it shows `^M` at the end of line then it means a DOS file that needs to be converted to Unix file

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[\(block 1\|blk 2\)\]\s*$/{n;h;s/\S.*/oranges = 5/p;s//pears = 2/p;x}' file
```

Locate the required match, print it and then store the next line in the hold space. Replace the first non-space character to the end of the line with the first required line, repeat for the second required string and then revert to the original line.