# How do you change column name in csv file with linux on Mac

Tags: linux

Simply just want to change few column names in a csv file and store it as it is using this code:

`sed -i -e "1s/oldcolname/" -e "1s/newcolname/" xxx.csv`.

But it does not work. I got the error message :

`sed: 1: "1s/oldcolname/":unterminated substitute in regular expression`.

Anyone knows how to rewrite it? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is wrong with my string substitution using sed on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592043/what-is-wrong-with-my-string-substitution-using-sed-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply replace `oldcolname` with `newcolname`, here's a quick answer:

```
sed -i -e 's/oldcolname/newcolname/' your_file.csv
```