# Shell script: Command not found

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, line-endings

I'm scripting a file which will change the permissions of a file once it is run. I keep getting these errors on the Cygwin terminal:

```
$ chmx.bash
/home/user/scripts/chmx.bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/home/user/scripts/chmx.bash: line 4: $'\r': command not found
chmod: cannot access ‘chmxtext.txt\r\r’: No such file or directory
```

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileName="chmxtext.txt"
chmod a+rwx "$fileName"
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some windows-style newline characters. Check the [info on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) on how to remove them

Comment: @arco444 I upvoted your comment but it should really be posted as an answer so that Matthew has the opportunity to accept it.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I disagree - Really the question should be closed as off topic due to typographical error or as a duplicate as I'm sure there must be other posts that already contain the contents of the comment as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['\r': command not found - .bashrc / .bash\_profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile)