# Zeppelin Errors

Tags: bash, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to install Zeppelin on windows 10, but getting errors while running the command - bash zeppelin-daemon.sh start. I have configured JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME manually by going to the properties of my_computer (not by cmd or shell commands), can that be the reason for the errors?

Below are the errors I am getting -

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Harneet/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/conf/zeppelin-env.sh line 18:
$'\r': command not found
/cygdrive/c/Users/Harneet/zeppelin-0.6.0-bin-all/conf/zeppelin-env.sh line 20:
': not a valid identifier
```

Please help?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile

Comment: Why are you running bash and not windows - native cmd? Try this in the Windows command prompt: c:\MyPath\zeppelin>bin\zeppelin.cmd