# Cygwin adding '$'\r' to files, mv : cannot stat

Tags: cygwin

I'm using a single line in cygwin to move files from a list to another folder.

`$ for file in $(cat list.txt); do mv "$file" destination; done`

Half the files are fine and go where they belong but the rest provide the error "mv: cannot stat 'filename.pdf'$'\r': No such file or directory".
How do I get around this error so the remaining files will move?

Comment: It looks like your list.txt file contains DOS-newlines (\r\n) which confuses Cygwin.  You can convert the file to Unix-style newlines (\n) with the dos2unix command.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693127/cygwin-r-command-not-found-error?rq=1

Comment: I saw that question but didn't understand the answer until just now. Thank you.

Comment: Cant even rename some files. Trillion dollar OS