# ' not found in root project 'project_name'. Some candidates are: 'fatJar'

Tags: bash, gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run Windows 10 bash.exe to run the bash script. I face a wired situation that if I add anything below `gradle fatJar` in bash it throws an error.

Bash script:(Not working)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf build
gradle fatJar
echo 'Success'
```

> ' not found in root project 'project_name'. Some candidates are:
>   'fatJar'.

Bash script:(Working)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf build
gradle fatJar
```

Why I cannot add anything below `gradle fatJar`? This happens only in Windows 10 bash. In mac, both work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out my self. Hope this answer might help someone.

After a bit of playing around, I found that if I write everything in a single line using `&&` everything worked fine eg:`rm -rf build&&gradle fatJar&&echo 'Success'` then I realized some wrong with the line breaks. It was adding `\r` to ever line break.

After a bit of research, I found the cause. It happened because I committed the file in In Mac IntelliJ then later I edited the file in Windows IntelliJ, that last edit changed the Line Separator format of the bash file to `CRLF Windows (\r\n)` which was adding `\r` internal to every line breaks.

I changed the line separator to  `LF UNIX and OS X (\n)` and boom everything worked as expected.

To change line separator in IntelliJ follow [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-separators.html) and for others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile)