# entrypoint.sh - line 9: syntax error: unexpected "("

Tags: bash, docker, entry-point

I am trying to run the following script from docker (based on alpine image)

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "test"

export USERNAME="AQICAHj456mvH8iSJofL46Xtr7KP6Ng3Vn5k6BpZbkAAAAZTBjBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagVjBUAgEAME8GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMwCm8C+wSLRm/+sSuAgEQgCJHCFbrIwCQuH0x2iGp13j9SuxMtfrcE6c4SmrHRVkkX24f"
export AWS_REGION="us-east-1"
echo "$AWS_REGION"

decrypt=$(aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo "$USERNAME" | base64 -d))
export $key="$(echo $decrypt | jq .Plaintext -r | base64 -d)"

exec "$@"
```

I am getting the below output

```
test
us-east-1
/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

I am not sure how to resolve this syntax error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: When I use `#!/bin/bash` I am getting this error `[FATAL tini (6)] exec /bin/entrypoint.sh failed: No such file or directory`. It is not able to recognize this as shell script

Comment: You probably have CRLF line endings, fix that with `dos2unix`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I am running this from Mac OS X

Comment: [how to install dos2unix on mac](https://brewinstall.org/install-dos2unix-on-mac-with-brew/)

Comment: tried doing `sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' entrypoint.sh` on mac and pasted the text in the `entrypoint.sh` file. It did not work

Comment: `\n` should be `\r`

Comment: `sed 's/\r//' entrypoint.sh > new_entrypoint.sh`

Comment: I am still getting the same error. `#!/bin/sh` worked until halfway. Also wanted to remind this is alpine image

Comment: Please make up your mind: Do you want to use `sh`,  or do you want to use `bash`? It doesn't make sense to discuss a program, if you don't have settled which language to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<(...)` is a `bash` extension, it's not available in `/bin/sh`. You don't need it for your script, you should be using `$(...)` there.

```
decrypt=$(aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://$(echo "$USERNAME" | base64 -d))
```

Comment: Now it tried to do something. I am getting an error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 12: invalid start byte`

Comment: That's a Python error coming from `kms decrypt`, nothing to do with bash.  Google it.