# line 21: $'\r': command not found in wsl

Tags: bash, command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a test.sh script file. I am using WSL2.

I am currently inside `mnt/d/solid/test` folder after running the command `bash tests.sh`
it gives error

`/mnt/d/solid/scripts/common.sh: line 21: $'\r': command not found`.

Why this is executing inside `scripts` folder instead `test` folder.

I also tried this [https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616835/r-command-not-found-bashrc-bash-profile).

But still getting same error

Comment: you saved the script as CRLF, not LF. Convert it to LF an it'll work fine

Comment: @phuclv I have already tried LF ending. Doesn't work. Neither the method given in the link it's also doesn't work

Comment: tried what? Is the output really LF? Show the commands you tried. Run `file /mnt/d/solid/scripts/common.sh` to see. Or if you have Notepad++, VS Code or VS open the file with them and check the line ending tyope

Comment: I have a doubt, When I am executing file inside `test` folder, then why does it's running file in`scripts` folder ?

Comment: your script can `cd` into another folder as it wants. Nothing prevents it from doing that

Comment: Thankyou got it. I have to change all the script file ending to LF.