# Why am I getting errors on my pre-commit when trying to commit staged changes via git in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2022

I have a .Net solution in Visual Studio 2022 on a Windows box.
I am attempting to commit staged changes via git in VS.

I have a pre-commit in my .githooks folder.
**It contains the following:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LC_ALL=C

local_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

valid_branch_regex="^(NameA|NambB|NameC|NameD)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,35}$"

message="There is something wrong with your branch name"

if [[ ! $local_branch =~ $valid_branch_regex ]]
then
    echo "$message"
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

When I attempt to commit the staged changes **I get the following errors**:

> .githooks/pre-commit: line 3: $'\r': command not found
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 4: git: command not found
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 5: $'\r': command not found
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 7: $'\r': command not found
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 9: $'\r': command not found
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 10: syntax error in conditional expression
> .githooks/pre-commit: line 10: syntax error near `]] ' .githooks/pre-commit: line 10:` if [[ ! $local_branch =~
> $valid_branch_regex ]] '

I tried doing a little research on this and I found something referring to  a problem with the line endings in the Git hook script. The error message suggests that the script contains a carriage return (\r) character, which is not being recognized correctly.

I tried editing the file in a text editor to clean up potential line ending issues. I still see the same problem.

Other team members are not having any issues.
What exactly is going on here and how do I correct it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252010/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617204/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshell%5D+%27%5Cr%27%3A+command+not+found

Comment: @phd - thx for clearing that up