# bashrc unexpected end of file error/ hadoop

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, apache-spark

i am getting this error.

```
-bash: .bashrc: line 122: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Could you look at the my bashrc

```
cat -An ~/.bashrc | tail -3
   119  export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native$
   120  export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin$
   121  export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin$
```

Thanks

Comment: also when i take like a commend #export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native$
      #export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin$
     #export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin$ ---getting same error

Comment: I think $ symbol at the end of every line in unnecessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886268/shell-script-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file

Comment: i found the result.just miss a fi

Comment: @Jeyaram The `$` is from the `-A` option passed to `cat`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for that. I never used that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you didn't set it correctly please follow this:

vi $HOME/.bashrc
put the following lines at the end of the file: (change the hadoop home as yours)

```
 # Set Hadoop-related environment variables 
 export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

 # Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on) 
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun

 # Some convenient aliases and functions for running Hadoop-related commands 
  unalias fs &> /dev/null
  alias fs="hadoop fs"
  unalias hls &> /dev/null 
  alias hls="fs -ls"

 # If you have LZO compression enabled in your Hadoop cluster and
 # compress job outputs with LZOP (not covered in this tutorial):
 # Conveniently inspect an LZOP compressed file from the command
 # line; run via:
 #
 # $ lzohead /hdfs/path/to/lzop/compressed/file.lzo
 #
 # Requires installed 'lzop' command.
  lzohead () {
     hadoop fs -cat $1 | lzop -dc | head -1000 | less 
    }

 # Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
  export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```