# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Now I am developing iphone app.

I created xcodescript.sh.

But build failed.

Error message is:

```
xcodescript.sh: line 2: 
: command not found
xcodescript.sh: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

And My xcodescript.sh content is:

```
#!/bin/sh

BIN_DIR="bin"
if [ ! -d "$BIN_DIR" ]; then
mkdir -p "$BIN_DIR"
fi

BIN_DIR_TMP="bin_tmp"
if [ ! -d "$BIN_DIR_TMP" ]; then
mkdir -p "$BIN_DIR_TMP"
fi


DST_DIR1="./../wfchat/Frameworks"
if [ ! -d "$DST_DIR1" ]; then
mkdir -p "$DST_DIR1"
fi

DST_DIR2="./../wfuikit/Frameworks"
if [ ! -d "$DST_DIR2" ]; then
mkdir -p "$DST_DIR2"
fi

cp -af ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/ 
${BIN_DIR_TMP}/${PLATFORM_NAME}-${TARGET_NAME}.framework
cp -af ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/ ${BIN_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework
lipo -create $BIN_DIR_TMP/*-${TARGET_NAME}.framework/${TARGET_NAME} -output 
${BIN_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/${TARGET_NAME}

cp -af ${BIN_DIR}/* ${DST_DIR1}/
cp -af ${BIN_DIR}/* ${DST_DIR2}/
```

Please help me. Thanks and Regards

Comment: This may help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886268/shell-script-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file

Comment: Sorry. I am freshman in ios developer. So please let me know what I have to do for fix this issue.