# File is not getting copied inside Docker container using cp command in a script

Tags: linux, docker, nginx

I am trying to run a custom-nginx server in Docker with a custom configuration file(Let's call it `custom.configuration.conf`)

And, I want the container to pick the configuration file based on the deployment environment. Hence in my repository, I have put the configuration as follows:

```
configuration(folder)
|
----> qa (sub-folder of configuration folder)
     |
     ----> custom.configuration.conf
|      
----> prd (sub-folder of configuration folder)
      |
      ---> custom.configuration.conf
```

To pick these files dynamically I introduced an environment variable `DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT` which I'm using in a file named `start.sh`

The `start.sh` script is as follows:

```
cp configuration/${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}/custom.configuration.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM nginx:1.23-alpine as application
WORKDIR /build
COPY configuration configuration
COPY start.sh start.sh
ENTRYPOINT /build/start.sh
```

The commands I'm using to build and run the container are:

```
docker build -t custom-nginx .
```

```
docker run -e DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=qa -p 8080:80 custom-nginx
```

However, when I `docker exec` into the container I can't see the `custom.configuration.conf` at `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

I'm running this on a Windows 10 machine with Docker Desktop.

`start.sh`, `Dockerfile` and `configuration` folder/files are at the root level in my repository.

I don't understand where I am going wrong. Please help me understand why am I not able to copy the file from container to container.

P.S: I actually tried running the `cp configuration/${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}/custom.configuration.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d` command inside the container to check if the command was wrong. However, it works if I do it manually inside the container, but fails when I run it using `docker run`.

Comment: Why not follow https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I referred to it. However, I could not find anything related to my use-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've performed the **EOL conversion from Windows(CR LF) to Unix(LF)** as directed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212715/6123155 and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add error handling to your entrypoint.sh script:

```
cp -v configuration/${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}/custom-configuration.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
if [ "$?" != "0" ]
then
    echo "Could not copy configuration for DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT=${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}!"
    exit 1
fi
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Now check the docker logs when running the container. They should give you more hints of what happened.

Comment: Getting the following error now:
 `
'configuration/qa/custom-configuration.conf' -> '/etc/nginx/conf.d
 /build/start.sh: 7: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
`

Comment: Please share your whole entrypoint.sh script. I suspect some whitespace got scrambled.

Comment: I just googled this issue and the answer by David Gidony I found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/50212715/6123155 fixed both of my problems - the issue above and the original question too. The issue was due to a mismatch between Windows and Unix EOL. Anyway, thanks for your help, too!