# How to specify a system independent classpath

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I need to run a java command with a custom classpath.

On Windows I need to type:

```
java -cp foo;bar
```

On Linux I need to type:

```
java -cp foo:bar
```

We currently have a .bat file containing the first version and a .sh file containing the second version. This works fine most of the time, but fails for git-bash on Windows, which needs a shell script with a semicolon delimiter.

Is there any system independent way to write such a classpath?

I would think of something like

```
java -cp foo -cp bar
```

but this does not this way.

Currently the only way I see is having some shell logic determining the OS and generating the correct command line from that.

Is there an easier way to do this the java way?

Comment: How you can run a shell script under windows?

Comment: Yes, bash is available for windows, too. For example if you install git, it contains a really nice shell: git-bash.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The closest thing that comes to mind is to put the classpath information in a manifest and package it in a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify it at all. Use the 'java -jar' command, naming a JAR file with a Manifest.MF containing a Main-Class attribute, and if necessary a Class-Path attribute, specifying the *relative* locations of any other JARs this one depends on. As this is done via space-separated relative URLs, it is automatically system-independent.

Comment: *As this is done via relative URLs, it is automatically system-independent.* -- Seems to indicate that you believe that the *paths* that are problematic. Java accepts class paths with `/` both on Windows and *nix. It's the *path separators* that are platform specific.

Comment: Does the Class-Path attribute allow the use of wildcards like `lib/*`? (A quick test did not work.) The paths in the classpath are relative to the current working directory, right?

Comment: No, class path wild cards are not supported in manifest files. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html : *However, class path wildcards are not honored in the Class-Path jar-manifest header.* They are supported when provided on the class path though.

Comment: @aiiobe No, I believe the paths may be *part* of the problem. The OP indicates that the path separator is his main problem.

Comment: @michas I don't see why you need a wildcard. You know the required JAR files in advance, and you have to distribute them with your application. Wildcard *ergo* not required.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem the maven way: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html 

Maven generates the correct Manifest entries and I can simply use 'java -jar'.

Comment: in the Class-Path entry in the manifest, the folder separators are platform specific, java was not able to resolve path with / in windows and when I changed the manifest and replaced / with \ it worked.
Is there a way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 4):

- **Option 1:** If you don't mind creating a jar before running, you could specify the classpath in a manifest file. Those paths are space-separated. (See [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html))
- **Option 2** Add code for detecting OS using for instance `uname`. Then do either `SEP=\;` or `SEP=:` and use `path${SEP}path`. (See for instance [How to check if running in Cygwin, Mac or Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466166/how-to-check-if-running-in-cygwin-mac-or-linux))
- **Option 3:** Grep the java help output to see what separator character java expects:

  ```
  SEP=$(java -h |& grep "A [:;] separated" | grep -o "[:;]")
  ```
- **Option 4:** If you have the JDK installed, you can print the `File.pathSeparator`:

  ```
  echo "interface C { static void main(String[] a) { System.out.print(java.io.File.pathSeparator); }}" > C.java
  javac C.java
  java C
  rm C.{java,class}
  ```

---

**Note:** Only the *path separators*, i.e. `;` vs `:`, are platform specific. Forward slashes (i.e. `some/class/path`) work fine on all systems for separating directories.

Comment: Current option 3 (`SEP=$(java -h |& grep "A [:;] separated" | grep -o "[:;]")`) only works for an English locale. 

Here is my take (successfully tested on German *Windows 7* and English *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*): `SEP=$(  [ $(java -h |& grep ";" | wc -l ) == 1 ] && echo ";" || echo ":"  )`

Comment: Option 3 must be a joke.

Comment: @0xF, it's a bit hacky, but if you think of it, the `java` command on the running system is the single source of truth for what separator symbol `java` accepts. The `java -h` happens to print the correct symbol. Added a fourth option which is perhaps less hacky, but requires the JDK.