# Is there a command working on BOTH linux and mac OS for determining the OS version?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I know there is, for example, `hostnamectl` command on linux and `system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType` command on macOS to know the operating system version, but I'm looking for a command that works for both operating systems. Does it exist?

Comment: `uname -v` is probably the closest you can get. Its *output*, though, isn't particularly standardized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394230/608639), [How to check if running in Cygwin, Mac or Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466166/608639), [uname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uname) on Wikipedia, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `uname -s` with `tr` inside `Makefile` to determine the system and decide whether to use `.so` od `.dylib`.

On macOS

```
> uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
darwin
```

On Linux

```
> uname -s | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
linux
```