# How to check whether shell scripts / Vim running in VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, visual-studio-code, zsh

#### Issue

Question is as stated in the title.

In gist, I am trying to get my bash scripts and Vim to behave differently when running in VS Code's integrated terminal.

#### Things I've found

I have managed to find several other Stack Overflow questions, but they relate to detection of operating systems:
- [How to check if running in Cygwin, Mac or Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466166/how-to-check-if-running-in-cygwin-mac-or-linux)
- [How to detect the OS from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/how-to-detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script/18434831)

Comment: Environment variables are the best way to do that... Can you configure the shell in VS Code to export a unique environment variable you can use for detection? Or can you check the environment in your VS Code shell to see if it already includes a variable you could use for this detection?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By examining the shell variables in the vscode terminal you can see that it sets `TERM_PROGRAM=vscode`. In my .bash_profile I have the following and it works great:

```
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "vscode" ]; then
    # some stuff
else
    # other stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the parent process until it matches or you find PID==1

```
#! /bin/bash

pid=$$
until (( pid == 1 ))
do
    [[ $(ps -o command= -p $pid) =~ Code ]] && break
    pid=$(ps -o ppid= $pid)
done

(( pid != 1 )) && echo "VS Code"
```

Check `man ps` in case yours have different options