Command runs before shell in terminal is started
I have a strange problem: when an extension, for example quarto when on rendering, or SQLTools when starting, is running a command in the terminal, that command is send before the terminal is started:

This leads to either an error message which I have to confirm (in the case of SQLTools) or nothing happening in the case of rendering in quarto.
Any ideas how I can fix this?
Here are the non-default settings from the integrated terminal in the user settings:
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash",
  "terminal.integrated.tabs.defaultColor": "terminal.ansiRed",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
      "bash": {
        "path": "bash",
        "args": [
          "-l"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
      },
      "zsh": {
        "path": "zsh",
        "args": [
          "-l"
        ]
      },
      "fish": {
        "path": "fish",
        "args": [
          "-l"
        ]
      },
      "tmux": {
        "path": "tmux",
        "icon": "terminal-tmux"
      },
      "pwsh": {
        "path": "pwsh",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
      }
    },
  "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "FIG_NEW_SESSION": "1",
    "CW_NEW_SESSION": "1"
  },

==========
Edit 1:
Added the last lines of the output when starting bash with -x option - let me know when you need more info :
+++ CW_SHELL=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/bash/5.2.26/bin/bash
+++ CW_IS_LOGIN_SHELL=1
+++ exec -a 'bash (cwterm)' '/Users/rainerkrug/.local/bin/bash (cwterm)'
quarto preview /Users/rainerkrug/Documents_Local/git/WBF_2024/index.qmd --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
                              --   --   (main  origin)     
ieu0675-rkrug:WBF_2024 rainerkrug$ it/WBF_2024/index.qmd --no-browser --no-watch-inputs
bash: it/WBF_2024/index.qmd: No such file or directory
                              --   --   (main  origin)     
ieu0675-rkrug:WBF_2024 rainerkrug$ 


I can't see from your screenshot, that the command was executed, before the shell started. I can at best conclude tht the command was executed before  the shell displayed for the first time its prompt. If you guess otherwise, you should start your shell with bash -x, so that you see what really happens, and when.

To clarify: the command is send, but no=t executed (i.e. not run). So the terminal window is started, the command is send and arrives in the terminal window, and only after that base is started and is running. I add the output with the -x to the question.

I don't see in the VSC configuration, where you have placed the -x (I would have suspected that the bash args say i.e. -lx and not just -x), so I feel we are missing something. Also you are doing an exec of another shell (bash (cwterm)). Assuming that this is just an oddly named, different build of bash, you would have to pass -x to this shell again, because otherwise you don't see what happens there. Plus, for this kind of problem, I recommend that you post a screenshot to the output you get with -x, not pasting it here as text.

The bash (cwterm) I saw as well - it is the CodeWhisperer shell. I will try it without it and let you know.

@user1934428 Thanks - that was the problem.

OK - I found the problem. It was CodeWhisperer . I commented all references to it out in the .bashrc and .bash_profile files and now it is working again (thanks @user1934428 !).
But if anybody could point me on how I can use it in the terminal without interfering with VSCode terminal, please let me know.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/57635562/11107541
