# Windows bash shells: How to robustly identify which flavor is running

Tags: bash, cygwin, git-bash

I operate in an environment that uses both git-bash and cygwin bash.  There are probably other flavors as well.  What is the easiest way to robustly identify which bash flavor is running?

IMPLEMENTATION NOTE: There are a lot of non-trivial ways to do this; there are a lot of ways to make potential solutions fail.

Here's how one developer does this:
Update the .bashrc by adding an environment variable.  In scripts, check the value of the environment variable.  Pro: easy.  Con: This requires the modification of 2 .bashrc files.

Comment: We're here to help you fix code that isn't working. We'll need to see samples and error messages. Please update your Q with your best attempt to solve your problem. Good lulck.\

Comment: Why does it matter? What will you do differently in one bash versus the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uname -s` should be enough:

- Git for Windows bash:

  ```
  MINGW64_NT-10.0-18363
  ```
- Cygwin bash (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3466166/6309))

  ```
  CYGWIN_NT-5.1
  ```

Comment: Added pro: version numbers!  I doubt it can get much simpler than that!  Thanks.  I'm curious if this works with other Windows bash shell flavors.

Comment: @RichardJessop You can see an example for mintty: https://github.com/mintty/mintty/issues/885

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It contains information that other script developers will find useful if they need additional environment attributes.

Comment: With WSL bash, output is `Linux`