# Makefile that distinguishes between Windows and Unix-like systems

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, os-detection

I would like to have the same Makefile for building on Linux and on Windows. I use the default *GNU make* on Linux and the  *mingw32-make* (also *GNU make*) on Windows.

I want the Makefile to detect whether it operates on Windows or Linux.

---

For example `make clean` command on Windows looks like:

```
clean:
    del $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
```

But on Linux:

```
clean:
    rm $(DESTDIR_TARGET)
```

Also I would like to use different directory separator on Windows (`\`) and Linux (`/`).

---

**It is possible to detect Windows operating system in Makefile?**

PS: *I do not want to emulate Linux on Windows (cygwin etc.)*

There is similiar question: [OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile), but I didn't find the answer here.

Comment: Windows is able to handle both slashes "/" and "\" are equivalent.

Comment: If this is for a substantial project, I wonder if it'd be worth letting autotools handle some of the portability stuff?

Comment: @Jefromi: autotools assumes a basic UNIX toolset (sh, m4, sed, rm, ...).  @tomp: Might as well install them on windows (from MSYS or GnuWin) and spend your efforts on the more challenging portability issues.

Comment: @ephemient: Ah, right, my bad. I'm not really a windows person. (But now I'm confused - can't the mingw toolchain provide that too? I know, the OP said no linux emulation.)

Comment: @Ency, the "del" command on Windows doesn't like to be given a "/".

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I solved this by looking for an env variable that will only be set on windows.

```
ifdef OS
   RM = del /Q
   FixPath = $(subst /,\,$1)
else
   ifeq ($(shell uname), Linux)
      RM = rm -f
      FixPath = $1
   endif
endif

clean:
    $(RM) $(call FixPath,objs/*)
```

Because %OS% is the type of windows, it should be set on all Windows computers but not on Linux.

The blocks then setups up variables for the different programs as well as a function for converting the forward slashes into backslashes.

You to have to use $(call FixPath,path) when you call an outside command (internal commands work fine).  You could also use something like:

```
/ := /
```

and then

```
objs$(/)*
```

if you like that format better.

Comment: Thanks for this. I switch between MinGW on Windows and GCC on Linux, this works great.

Comment: In mingw it should be `SYSTEMROOT` in uppercase

Comment: You can also check for ComSpec, that is only defined on Windows

Comment: If you're running COMMAND.COM for some reason, you should also be checking for SYSTEMROOT in uppercase: "SystemRoot" won't be defined with that capitalisation (whereas it will in CMD.EXE).

Comment: Updated example to use the upper case version of SYSTEMROOT

Comment: System root is sensitive in mingw32-make and it doesn't work after either.

Comment: There is already $(RM) in make environments, already depending on OS.

Comment: In GnuWin32's `make` the predefined variable `$(RM)` expands to `rm -f` in CMD.EXE

Answer (score 51):

The SystemRoot trick didn't work for me on Windows XP but this did:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    #Windows stuff
    ...
else
    #Linux stuff
    ....
endif
```

Comment: this might be tricky if you have cygwin installed and make executable comes from cygwin. You will get OS=Windows_NT but you can use Linux commands like mkdir -p. The direction of the directory separator is also important

Answer (score 10):

You should probably use the $(RM) variable to remove some files.

Answer (score 2):

Checking WINDIR or COMSPEC is case-sensitive.  Instead, I came up
with the following solution,  hope that helps someone someday:

```
# detect if running under unix by finding 'rm' in $PATH :
ifeq ($(wildcard $(addsuffix /rm,$(subst :, ,$(PATH)))),)
WINMODE=1
else
WINMODE=0
endif

ifeq ($(WINMODE),1)
# native windows setup :
UNLINK = del $(subst /,\,$(1))
CAT = type $(subst /,\,$(1))
else
# cross-compile setup :
UNLINK = $(RM) $(1)
CAT = cat $(1)
endif
```

Comment: If using cygwin or in a mingw shell, you'd have `rm` in path and still be in windows.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to have the same Makefile for building on Linux and on Windows.

Maybe you will like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)

Comment: Please put the explanation how to use tool