# tell if make is running on windows or linux

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, os-agnostic, os-detection

Is there a way to know in makefiles if GNU make is running on a linux OS or a windows OS?

I've built a bash script that generates a makefile for building my app and it works fine on my Debian machine. I want to try to build it on MinGW/MSYS, but the problem is that I have to build and run some test programs that check errors in source code, and to run it on Windows, I must add the .exe suffix.

Comment: It's Time to use Maven. It is platform independent.

Comment: To sidestep this particular issue, you could just include the .exe suffix on _all_ platforms; Linux won't mind it if it's there, as long as you remember to include it when running the program.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile

Comment: @Michaelangel007 Disagree that this is a duplicate.  I searched for this specific question about .exe on different OSes, but Google showed first the question you referenced, which had no direct answer, only a collection of various techniques to identify an OS, not specifically how to optionally add a ".exe" file extension solely for the platforms that use it.  The other techniques may allow for a wider range of more generic solutions to similar problems, but it's not the same as a duplicate answering or even asking this specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[uname](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuname.htm) command should give you the basic info about the OS. Can you use that, and then make an IF based on the return value?

As not to rewrite everything, here - these two questions may be of some interest to you
[1. OS detecting makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile)
[2. Makefile that distincts between Windows and Unix-like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058840/makefile-that-distincts-between-windows-and-unix-like-systems)

Comment: thanks, i think this should work. maybe add some code for ignoring versions, so that it can work on different relases

Comment: Makefiles I've invoked from Powershell have failed when I try this, since they can't find uname. For MinGW/MSYS, maybe you could just have your makefile check for the `$MSYSTEM` environment variable? Though that won't help in Cygwin.

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE**
>   Please read this similar but better answer:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777895/938111

---

`make` (and `gcc`) can be easily installed on MS-Windows using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started).

As @ldigas says, `make` can detect the platform using `UNAME:=$(shell uname)` (the command `uname` is also installed by Cygwin or MinGW installer).

Below, I provide a complete example based on `make` (and `gcc`) to explain how to build a shared library: `*.so` or `*.dll` depending on the platform.

The example is basic/simple to be easily understandable :-)

Let's see the five files:

```
 ├── app
 │   └── Makefile
 │   └── main.c
 └── lib
     └── Makefile
     └── hello.h
     └── hello.c
```

### The `Makefiles`

`app/Makefile`

```
app.exe: main.o
        gcc -o $@ $^ -L../lib -lhello
        # '-o $@'    => output file => $@ = the target file (app.exe)
        # '   $^'    => no options => Link all depended files 
        #            => $^ = main.o and other if any
        # '-L../lib' => look for libraries in directory ../lib
        # '-lhello   => use shared library hello (libhello.so or hello.dll)

%.o: %.c
        gcc -o $@ -c $< -I ../lib
        # '-o $@'     => output file => $@ = the target file (main.o)
        # '-c $<'     => COMPILE the first depended file (main.c)
        # '-I ../lib' => look for headers (*.h) in directory ../lib

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.dll *.exe
```

`lib/Makefile`

```
UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
TARGET = libhello.so
else
TARGET = hello.dll
endif

$(TARGET): hello.o
        gcc  -o $@  $^  -shared
        # '-o $@'    => output file => $@ = libhello.so or hello.dll
        # '   $^'    => no options => Link all depended files => $^ = hello.o
        # '-shared'  => generate shared library

%.o: %.c
        gcc  -o $@  -c $<  -fPIC
        # '-o $@' => output file => $@ = the target file (hello.o)
        # '-c $<' => compile the first depended file (hello.c)
        # '-fPIC' => Position-Independent Code (required for shared lib)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.dll *.exe
```

### The source code

`app/main.c`

```
#include "hello.h" //hello()
#include <stdio.h> //puts()

int main()
{
    const char* str = hello();
    puts(str);
}
```

`lib/hello.h`

```
#ifndef __HELLO_H__
#define __HELLO_H__

const char* hello();

#endif
```

`lib/hello.c`

```
#include "hello.h"

const char* hello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

### The build

Fix `Makefiles` copy (replace leading spaces by tabulation).

```
> sed  -i  's/^  */\t/'  */Makefile
```

The `make` command is the same on both platforms. This is the output on MS-Windows (removed unnecessary lines).

```
> cd lib
> make clean
> make
gcc  -o hello.o  -c hello.c  -fPIC
gcc  -o hello.dll  hello.o  -shared
> cd ../app
> make clean
> make
gcc -o main.o -c main.c -I ../lib
gcc -o app.exe main.o -L../lib -lhello
```

### The run

The application requires to know where is the shared library.

On MS-Windows, the simple/basic/stupid way is to copy the library where the application is:

```
> cp -v lib/hello.dll app
`lib/hello.dll' -> `app/hello.dll'
```

On Linux, use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib
```

The run command line and output are the same on both platforms:

```
> app/app.exe
hello
```