# "No such module" error when trying to get Mocha to watch my project

Tags: node.js, windows-7, mocha.js

I'm trying to get Mocha to watch my project for test and constantly run the tests but when I use the `-w` flag I get an error.

Here the test executes fine:

```
C:\Foo>mocha

  .

  ? 1 tests complete (3ms)
```

and here with `-w`

```
C:\Foo>mocha -w


node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: No such module
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (node.js:392:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:203:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I have Mocha installed globally (`npm install -g mocha`) and should installed locally to the project.

I'm using node v0.6015, Mocha 1.0.1 and Should 0.6.1 on 64bit Windows 7 home premium.

Comment: @jibsales Via NPM, see the line below the error above.

Comment: My apologies, I meant how did you install Node

Comment: Via the Windows installer from nodejs.org

Comment: This error [appears fixed](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1553) in `node 0.8.9`, however Mocha now prints `watching` 10 times a second.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make it work on windows by changing a couple of mocha source code files.
After npm install mocha (in my case I installed it just for my project, not globally):

1) First go to **node_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js** find and fix *watch* function as follows:

```
exports.watch = function(files, fn) {
    var options = { interval: 100 };
    files.forEach(function(file) {
        debug('file %s', file);
        fs.watch(file, options, function(curr, prev) {
            fn(file);
        });
    });
};
```

I replaced fs.watchFile with fs.watch (see https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev/issues/26 for details) because the first one doesn't seem to work on windows.

2) Now open **node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha** and apply following fixes:

a) Find and comment out or remove following code:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function(){
  showCursor();
  console.log('\n');
  process.exit();
});
```

Since there's no equivalent of POSIX signals lines above have to be removed (ideally replaced by proper implementation, see [What is the Windows equivalent of process.on('SIGINT') in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021373/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-process-onsigint-in-node-js) for more details)

b) Find following code *utils.watch(watchFiles, function(){...* and replace it with

```
  var lastRun = new Date();
  utils.watch(watchFiles, function(){
    if (new Date() - lastRun > 300)
    {
        purge();
        stop()
        mocha.suite = mocha.suite.clone();
        ui = interfaces[program.ui](mocha.suite);
        loadAndRun();
        lastRun = new Date();
    }
  });
```

It throttles excessive callacks from fs.watch.

c) Last change is removing or commenting out this line:

```
  process.stdout.write('\r' + str);
```

in *function play(arr, interval)*. It just removes noise.

Comment: That's works fine, thank you for the solution. Do you know how to force it clear terminal after each restart?

Comment: The problem is that it restarts tests when any files are changed. But it does not take in to account changes (except changes in test file)

Comment: Haven't try to clear terminal. Picks up all file changes in my environment, though I have been only testing scripts in lib folder without any sub folders. Try having a look into _mocha, file monitoring is set up there if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install mocha locally into the project you're testing, looks like mocha didn't find required modules to use.

Also I think this should be helpful for you too:
[Mocha requires make. Can't find a make.exe that works on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779700/mocha-requires-make-cant-find-a-make-exe-that-works-on-windows)