# rerun mocha using supervisor... on windows

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, node-supervisor

I am trying to rerun mocha tests using supervisor. I have tried:

```
supervisor node_modules\.bin\mocha
```

It goes into loop with error:

```
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you want to do is `mocha -w`:

```
-w, --watch                     watch files for changes
```

It works nicely with the dot-matrix reporter (default) and `-G` to give you growl notifications when your tests fail.

Edit:

I've found the Windows-related issues you mention: ["No such module" error when trying to get Mocha to watch my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258248/no-such-module-error-when-trying-to-get-mocha-to-watch-my-project)

I can't help with that, either.

But back to the `supervisor` question: When I install mocha, the "bin" script is in node_modules/mocha/bin, and I can get tests to run repeatedly with the following

```
supervisor node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

supervisor does print some annoying `DEBUG` lines between each test run, but those can be silenced with `--quiet`. Because mocha quits after each run, you have a busy loop of constant tests, though.

Comment: I tried that but I get:
    var b = process.binding('signal_watcher');
    Error: No such module
        at
    process.startup.processSignalHandlers.process.on.process.addListener (node.js:468:27)

I understand it is a Windows issue and I have tried the work around. It resolves the error ok but then it is not successfully WATCHING for changes. I have to restart mocha to rerun tests.

This is why I was trying a 'supervisor' approach.

Comment: When I run quiet, it still doesn't rerun tests. An error is interfering. Trying a variety of approaches. I am running: supervisor node node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha  --require should --require server. It complains with: events.js:66
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event 
Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Comment: EADDRINUSE is usually a sign that the port you're trying to open is already used by another program. In your case you probably have your Express app running in a command line somewhere, and your tests are trying to start the same Express app on the same port, but can't.

Comment: I just realized that. Cake is launching on port 3000. So I launched manually like node server.js. Then I manually changed port to 3001 so that when test goes to launch server, it uses another port. I still was unable to get supervisor to work. I WAS ABLE however to use nodemon like: nodemon node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require should --require server. I will have to set ENV var to test or something so that it will use diff port for testing. Thank you for your input along the way.

Comment: One 'minor' detail is that I CANNOT see which test failed. It just says: ? 1 of 2 tests failed:
... [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: which `mocha reporter` are you using? some of them provide far more details than others. But maybe nodemon is trimming your output for you when it restarts an app... can't really tell.