# cygwin makefile on windows only runs first target

Tags: makefile, cygwin

Without further due and apologizing in case of RTFM is in order...

With this makefile:

```
aaa:
        @echo "aaa"

bbb:
        @echo "bbb"

.PHONY: aaa bbb
```

Shouldn't a "make bbb" output "bbb"?? I keep getting "aaa"

Can't a recipe be called directly?
Reading the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile) it seams like a direct call "make clean" can be made

Also I already checked that recipe indentation is a tab and not spaces

Should "make bbb" print "bbb"? Any idea why I'm getting "aaa"??

TIA

Comment: You are correct about what `make bbb` will do.  Given this makefile there's no way running `make bbb` will print `aaa`.  There's some difference between what you're really doing and what you've described here.

Comment: I really have no idea og what might be happening.
I using windows 7 64bits and installed cygwin 64 bits also.
I open the command windows on the folder containing the makefile,
do a "DOSKey make=C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe" and call "make bbb" and I get an "aaa" output.

Comment: I don't know what those things are (_DOSKey_ etc.)  If you're using the cygwin version of make, you need to invoke it from the cygwin shell.  This is true for all Cygwin tools: they are not plain native Windows applications; they only work in a Cygwin environment.  You cannot run them from command.com.  Probably what's happening is that the argument (`bbb`) is not being passed to the make command line properly, so `make` just runs the first target.  If you want to run make from the native Windows command window you should get the MinGW version of GNU make, not the cygwin version.

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. Using Cygwin shell does work. Trying your MinGW now. The thing that sent me in the cygwin directions was this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779700/mocha-requires-make-cant-find-a-make-exe-that-works-on-windows).
Because I had paths using square brackets I tried reproducing PowerShell Set-Alias with DOSKey