# How to make Application.mk OS specific

Tags: windows, android-ndk

I am trying to compile native code with AndroidNDK in both Windows and Ubuntu.  I would like to set APP_SHORT_COMMAND := true. But I only want to set this flag in Windows environment.  What is the syntax? I looked through the documentation and it doesn't mention anything OS specific. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ndk-build only launches gnu make. Application.mk follows syntax and rules for any other Makefile. Therefore, you can pick your answer here: [Makefile that distincts between Windows and Unix-like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058840/makefile-that-distincts-between-windows-and-unix-like-systems)

Your question is not an exact duplicate, but the answer is the same:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    #Windows stuff
    ...
else
    #Linux stuff
    ....
endif
```