# Import variables from C preprocessor into Makefile

Tags: makefile, c-preprocessor, cross-compiling

I want to create one Makefile for Windows and Linux builds. The problem is I have to link with different dynamic libraries for each platform. The C preprocessor may have few nice variables, for example `_WIN32`. How to extract this information?

The solution have to work with a cross compiler. I cannot create and then run a small program. I have only one, different variable, the `CC`, the environment may be the same.

The other way around is easy, the `-D` switch.

---

Similar but different questions:

[Makefile that distincts between Windows and Unix-like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058840/makefile-that-distincts-between-windows-and-unix-like-systems)
I use the same make program. Only the `CC` variable is different.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058840/makefile-that-distincts-between-windows-and-unix-like-systems

Comment: @racraman The question is about native build environments. I have cross compiler. (I’ve edited question a little.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer from [TTK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4540452/ttk)

Create file with variables, something like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
-lgdi32 -lopengl32
#else
-lpthread -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXcursor -lXrandr -lXinerama -lXi -lGL
#endif
```

And something like this to the Makefile:

```
A_FLAGS = $(strip $(shell $(CPP) -P $(CPPFLAGS) ./a_flags.cpp))
# or
A_FLAGS = $(strip $(shell $(CPP) -P -xc $(CPPFLAGS) ./a_flags))
```

`$(CPP)` – the C preprocessor executable, should be defined by the Make program
`-P` – the flag to inhibit generation of linemarkers
`-xc` – the flag to force preprocessor to treat file as C source
`$(CPPFLAGS)` – optional flags for the preprocessor defined by programmer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get directly those variables but you can try this solution:

```
CPP=i686-w64-mingw32-cpp
CPPFLAGS= -P
WIN32=$(shell echo _WIN32 | $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS))

iswin32:
    @echo $(WIN32)
```

This example will output 1:

```
$ make iswin32
1
```

If you are dealing with multiple declarations consider also creating a file with all the declarations, preprocess it and include it in a makefile.

```
$ cat declaration
WIN32 = _WIN32
```

Comment: The code doesn’t work, I got `cc: fatal error: no input files`, but the -P flag is enough help for me.

Comment: This is because `gcc` doesn't read from the stdin by default. Try to adding the flag `-xc -` this will tell `gcc` to read from the `stdin` and suggest the language (C in this case).