# How to detect OS in a make file?

Tags: makefile

I have a command that works one way in OSX/Unix and another in Debian/Linux. I want to create a make file for my application but need to detect the OS and issue the command accordingly. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OS detecting makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714100/os-detecting-makefile)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use **uname** to do this. In your Makefile, you could write something like:

```
OS := $(shell uname)
ifeq $(OS) Darwin
# Run MacOS commands 
else
# check for Linux and run other commands
endif
```

Comment: How can this code be executed inside of one of the targets?

Answer (score 19):

What worked for me

```
OS := $(shell uname)
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
  # Run MacOS commands
else
  # check for Linux and run other commands
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Use uname and an if statement as you do in shell commands, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773906/11755155).

```
.PHONY: foo

OS := $(shell uname)

foo:
    @if [ OS = "Darwin" ]; then\
      echo "Hello world";\
    fi
    @if [ OS = "Linux" ]; then\
      echo "Hello world";\
    fi
```

Note that the closing; and \ at each line are necessary

(This is because make interpret each line as a separate command unless it ends with )

Answer (score -1):

Use [autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system). It's a standard way of building portable source code packages.